# Syncing activity in PyQt QThreads

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I'm playing around with PyQt, and QThreads.  It seems that if I use the code that I've put in [this python fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/pyqt-syncing-problem) (note that the top section is auto-generated code from QtDesigner), where the current value of the loop is printed both in the loop in the slave thread and the loop controlling the progress bar, then the loops keep in sync, the values match at all points as the program runs, and the progress bar displays accurately the proportion of the slave thread completed.

In response to a comment below, this program in its current state actually does what I want it to - it just prints out, to the terminal, the value of the loop in the slave thread and the the value in the loop which controls the progression of the progress bar.

However, commenting out line 121 (i.e. if you don't print the current value in the progress bar loop), results in the progress bar reaching 100% (i.e. finishing 300 iterations) when the slave thread loop has only reached ~130 iterations (i.e. the progress bar completes about 100% faster).

Have I done something naïvely stupid / wrong - is there a better way to complete what I want to do?!

Comment: There is undoubtedly a better way to complete what you want to do, but I'm not clear on what it is you want to do. Could you elaborate on what your program is trying to accomplish? What do you intend to happen in the thread for example? In the meantime, I suggest reading the documentation on python threading. While you're not using python threads, there are plenty of synchronisation tools available which you can use from within a `QThread` such as `threading.Lock` or `threading.Event`.

Comment: I've tried to explain more clearly what this program does - it is only a test program so doesn't really have any major point; I'm just using it to try and learn threading...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because you have two loops doing the same number of iterations in different threads, does not mean they'll take the same length of time to complete. Generally, the contents of each iteration will take some amount of time to complete, and since your loops are doing different things, they'll (generally) take different lengths of time.

Further more, with threads in Python, The Global-Interpreter-Lock (GIL) blocks threads from running simultaneously on a multi-core CPU. The GIL is responsible for switching between threads, and continuing their execution, before switching to another, and then another, etc., etc. With QThreads, this becomes even more complex because Qt calls in a QThread can run without the GIL (so I understand) but general python code will still run with the GIL.

Because the GIL is responsible for handling what thread is running at any given time,  I've even seen two threads, doing exactly the same thing, run at different speeds. **As such, it is an entire coincidence that your two threads ever finished at the same time!**.

Note, that because of the GIL, two cpu-instensive tasks will have no speed benefit from running in separate threads. For that, you need to use multi-processing. However, if you want to farm out I/O bound tasks (such as user interface through a GUI in the main thread, network communication in another thread, aka, tasks that often spend a lot of time waiting for something outside of the program to trigger something) then threading is useful.

So, hopefully that helps explain threading, and what is going on in your program.

There are a couple of ways to do this better. One would be to keep the loop in your thread, but remove the other. Then use the qt signal/slot mechanism to call a function in `MainWindow` which runs one iteration of the loop that used to be there. This doesn't guarantee synchronisation though, only that your QThread will finish first (something could slow down the main thread so that events pile up and the function in `MainWindow` doesn't run until later). To complete the synchronisation, you could use a `threading.Event` object to make the QThread wait until the new function in `MainWindow` has run.

Example (untested, sorry, but hopefully gives the idea!):

```
import threading
#==========================================
class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):

    setTime = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int,int)
    iteration = QtCore.pyqtSignal(threading.Event, int)

    def run(self):

        self.setTime.emit(0,300)
        for i in range(300):
            time.sleep(0.05)
            event = threading.Event()
            self.iteration.emit(event, i)
            event.wait()

#==========================================
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    _uiform = None

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self._uiform = Ui_MainWindow()
        self._uiform.setupUi(self)
        self._uiform.runButton.clicked.connect(self.startThread)


    def startThread(self):
        self._uiform.progressBar.setRange(0,0)
        self.task = TaskThread()
        self.task.setTime.connect(self.changePB)
        self.task.iteration.connect(self.update_prog_bar)
        self.task.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int,int)
    def changePB(self, c, t):
        self.proportionFinished = int(math.floor(100*(float(c)/t)))
        self._uiform.progressBar.setValue(self.proportionFinished)

        self._uiform.progressBar.setRange(0,300)
        self._uiform.progressBar.setValue(0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(threading._Event,int)
    def update_prog_bar(self,event, i)
        self._uiform.progressBar.setValue(i+1)
        print i
        event.set()
```

Note the use of `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()` decorator is because of the issue documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752154/pyqt-connecting-a-signal-to-a-slot-to-start-a-background-operation). In short, when you use `signal.connect(my_function)`, you are omitting the second argument which determines the behaviour of the slot (whether it is executed immediately when `signal.emit()` is called, or whether it is executed once control returns to the event loop (aka, placed in a queue to be run later)). By default, this optional argument to connect tries to automatically decide which type of connection to make (see [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads)) which works usually. However if the connection is made before it knows that it is a connection between threads, and the "slot" is **not* explicitly defined as a slot using `@pyqtSlot`, pyQT gets confused!

**Additional info on decorators**: The simplest way to think of decorators is a shorthand for wrapping a function in another function. The decorator replaces your defined function with its own, and this new function usually uses your original function at some point. So in the `@pyqtSlot` case, the signal emission actually calls a pyqt function generated by `@pyqtSlot` and this function eventually calls the original function you wrote. The fact that the `@pyqtSlot` decorator takes arguments that match the types of the arguments of your slot, is an implementation detail of the pyqt decorator, and not representative of decorators in general. It is simply stating that your slot expects to be passed data of the specified types by a connected signal.

Comment: 'As such, it is an entire coincidence that your two threads ever finished at the same time!' - although I can accept this, I totally fail to understand why they finished at the same time on every one of the dozens of times I ran the program!

Comment: Using this code, I intially got `iteration = QtCore.pyqtSignal(threading.Event, int) TypeError: string or ASCII unicode expected not 'function'`; changing to `iteration = QtCore.pyqtSignal(threading._Event, int)` fixed it :) when running the program, I then got `TypeError: changePB() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
TypeError: update_prog_bar() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)` - the only way I could resolve this was to comment out the decorators - I don't understand decorators enough yet to know what they're for, what difference they make, or the explanation in the answer you linked to

Comment: Ah, I **think** (/ assume?) I've found the solution: the decorators take arguments that are python *types*: `@QtCore.pyqtSlot(int,int)` and `@QtCore.pyqtSlot(threading._Event, int)` works

Comment: @ChrisW Ah yes, my apologies. You have indeed worked it out correctly. I don't use the decorator very often myself, but have recently become aware that it is wise to use when threading! I'll update my post (And add in a couple of things about decorators and a bit more detail on the documented issue I linked to)