# PyQt crashing out as a Windows APPCRASH

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a [very short PyQt program](http://pythonfiddle.com/pyqt-crashing-example) (n.b. that is a PythonFiddle link - this seems to crash horribly in Firefox, so code is also posted below) which prints output to a `QTextEdit` (using code [from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356336/how-to-capture-output-of-pythons-interpreter-and-show-in-a-text-widget)). When I run the code (on Windows), it results in an APPCRASH.  Some observations:

- if I add a `time.sleep` call (i.e. uncomment out line 53), then the program completes fine
- if I don’t redirect the output to the QEdit (i.e. comment out line 34) then it works regardless of whether the `time.sleep` call is commented out or not

I assume that this implies that the code redirecting the `stdout` is broken somehow - but I'm struggling to understand what's wrong with it to result in this behaviour - any pointers gratefully received!

---

**Full error message**

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: pythonw.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    5193f3be
  Fault Module Name:    QtGui4.dll
  Fault Module Version: 4.8.5.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   52133a81
  Exception Code:   c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 00000000005cbdb7
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 5c9c
  Additional Information 2: 5c9c27bb85eb40149b414993f172d16f
  Additional Information 3: bc7e
  Additional Information 4: bc7e721eaea1ec56417325adaec101aa

---

Pythonfiddle crashes horribly on Firefox (for me at least), so code below too:

```
import os, sys, time, calendar, math
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class EmittingStream(QtCore.QObject): 
  textWritten = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

  def write(self, text): self.textWritten.emit(str(text))

class myWrapper(QtGui.QMainWindow):

  def __init__(self):
    super(myWrapper, self).__init__()
    self.toolbar = self.addToolBar("MainMenu")
    self.toolbar.addAction(QtGui.QAction("myProg", self, triggered=self.myProgActions))

  def myProgActions(self): self.setCentralWidget(myWidget())

class myWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

  def __init__(self):
    super(myWidget, self).__init__()

    self.myBtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Run!', self)
    self.myBtn.clicked.connect(self.startTest)
    self.outputViewer = QtGui.QTextEdit()

    self.grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    self.grid.addWidget(self.myBtn)
    self.grid.addWidget(self.outputViewer)
    self.setLayout(self.grid)

  def startTest(self):
    self.myLongTask = TaskThread()
    sys.stdout = EmittingStream(textWritten=self.normalOutputWritten)
    self.myLongTask.start()

  def normalOutputWritten(self, text):
    cursor = self.outputViewer.textCursor()
    cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
    cursor.insertText(text)
    self.outputViewer.setTextCursor(cursor)
    self.outputViewer.ensureCursorVisible()
    QtGui.qApp.processEvents()

class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):
  def __init__(self): super(TaskThread, self).__init__()
  def run(self): myProgClass()

class myProgClass:
  def __init__(self):
    for i in range(0,100):
      print "thread", i+1, " ", math.sqrt(i)
      #time.sleep(0.005)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  myApp = myWrapper()
  myApp.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, one thing first about the thread safety of your program. Because you are connecting a `QObject` to stdout, calls to `print` will interact with this `QObject`. But you should only interact with a `QObject` from the thread it was created in. The implementation you have is potentially thread **unsafe** if you call `print` from a thread other than the one the `QObject` resides in.

In your case, you are calling `print` from a `QThread` while the `EmmittingStream(QObject)` resides in the main thread. I suggest you thus change your code to make it threadsafe, like so:

```
self.myLongTask = TaskThread()
sys.stdout = EmittingStream(textWritten=self.normalOutputWritten)
sys.stdout.moveToThread(self.myLongTask)
self.myLongTask.start()
```

**Note that now calling `print` from the MainThread of your application will result in thread-unsafe behaviour. Since you aren't doing that at the moment, you are OK for now, but be warned!**

I really suggest you read http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html and get your head around everything it talks about. Understanding that document is the key to avoiding annoying crashes due to threads.

--

Now, The issue with the crash is apparently caused by your call to `processEvents()`. I haven't worked out **why** (I imagine it is related to threads somehow...), but I can tell you that you do not need that line! Because you are using signals/slots, once the `normalOutputWritten` method runs, control returns to the Qt Event Loop anyway, and it will continue to process events as normal. There is thus no need to force Qt to process events!

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:** For an example of how to make your `EmittingStream`/`print` calls thread-safe, see here: [Redirecting stdout and stderr to a PyQt4 QTextEdit from a secondary thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071448/redirecting-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-pyqt4-qtextedit-from-a-secondary-thread/21071865#21071865)

Comment: Thanks very much for the help - I had assumed it was a thread-safety issue but didn't really know where to start. Your initial advice works, but the program seems to wait until it is finished before it prints the output to the QTextEdit... I'll rewrite it using your other answer (and I'm grateful both to you for spending time on an answer and him for having a similar problem at the same time!)

Comment: @ChrisW Ah, my initial advice may not work because you need to decorate the `normalOutputWritten` method with `@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)`. It is likely  the same issue as the following link, but I missed it because I didn't see `connect` be explicitly called (I assume some magic in `QObject` is connecting the signal and slot automatically based on the keyword argument passed to `EmittingStream`)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752154/pyqt-connecting-a-signal-to-a-slot-to-start-a-background-operation

Comment: Hmm, the bad news is that adding the decorator doesn't change anything - I'm seriously out of my depth but too far along with this project to stop!

Comment: AH Ok, I've looked into it a bit more. At least on my system, it is updating the QTextEdit before the end, but it appears to be doing it in chunks. This is to be expected because you are basically firing off many many events from your thread, to the main thread, but the program is not switching back to the MainThread often enough to process them. I find this surprising! One solution is to synchronise the thread to the main thread, so that it only continues the next iteration once the QTextEdit has been updated. Is this Ok? It would help to know what you want to ultimately do in the thread

Comment: Hmm, offhand I wouldn't know how to synchronise the slave thread back to the main thread *goes off to Google*.  The bigger picture of how my code is organised is that I have a main GUI wrapper (`mainWrapper.py` which inherits a `QMainWindow`), a `QWidget` (in `myWidget.py`), and a module (`myProg.py`) where I set up the slave `QThread`. When a form is completed (to set parameters), and a button pressed, on the `QWidget`, the code (which uses these parameters) in `myWidget` is executed. I'm  then trying to show progess with a `QProgressBar` on the `QWidget`

Comment: Actually, you may have now realised where my question about progress bars which [you answered well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21041601/889604) fits in - it probably seemed a bit abstract - and why I want to be able to synchronise a progress bar loop with a separate loop where actual code is being executed

Comment: So the use of the `QTextEdit` is just a placeholder for a future `QProgressBar`? Also, out of interest, is this for a commercial project or just something you are personally playing with? I have some code I'll be releasing soon (hopefully within a week) which would probably solve all of your synchronisation problems, but it will be licensed under the BSD 2-clause license which might not suit you. Let me know!

Comment: Sorry - slight addition - I want to redirect the output from the code which does the actual work (i.e. in `myProg.py`) into the `QTextEdit`, so the user will have an idea from the `QProgressBar` how far along the program is, and will also have all the verbose info from the code doing the work. This code isn't for anything commercial :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45236/discussion-between-three-pineapples-and-chrisw)