# Introduce a text in a lineEdit of PyQt from a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

How can I introduce a text in a lineEdit from a thread that are getting the data whithout colapse the program? The important line is in the class "fil" where it shows Principal.self.aplicacio.actual_lineEdit.setText(self.temp)

```
    # !/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import serial
import threading
from time import sleep
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from temperaturaUI import Ui_Form


class Principal(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.aplicacio = Ui_Form()
        self.aplicacio.setupUi(self)

        self.aplicacio.sortir_Button.clicked.connect(exit)

        self.aplicacio.connectar_Button.clicked.connect(self.connectar)

    def connectar(self):
        try:
            arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
            print "Connectat amb èxit"
            temperatura = fil(0, arduino, self.aplicacio.actual_lineEdit)
            temperatura.start()
        except:
            print "Impossible connectar a l'Arduino"


class fil(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, temp, serie, line):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.temp = temp
        self.serie = serie
        self.line = line

    def run(self):
        try:
            while 1:
                self.temp = self.serie.readline()
                if self.temp != 0:
                     **Principal.self.aplicacio.actual_lineEdit.setText(self.temp)**
                sleep(0.2)
        except:
            print "Error al llegir de l'Arduino"



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    aplicacio = Principal()
    aplicacio.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your code does not run on it's own. Makes it more difficult to check what it's doing and what you want. Can you make the example shorter and self contained?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`signals`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html). You would add a signal to the `fil` class that emits the new text:

```
class fil(threading.Thread):
    update_line_edit = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, temp, serie, line):
        ...

    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                self.temp = self.serie.readline()
                if not self.temp:
                    update_line_edit.emit(self.temp)
        ...
```

Then, simply connect that signal to a `slot` function in your `Principal` class:

```
class Principal(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def connectar(self):
        try:
            arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
            print "Connectat amb èxit"
            temperatura = fil(0, arduino, self.aplicacio.actual_lineEdit)
            temperatura.change_line_edit.connect(self.update_line_edit)
        ...

    def update_line_edit(self, text):
        self.aplicacio.actual_lineEdit.setText(text)
```

Comment: The OP is using Python threads, not Qt threads, so you can't use signals like you have suggested.

Comment: @three_pineapples I haven't used signals in threads. However, their documentation does say: ['Connections may be made across threads.'](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html#new-style-signal-and-slot-support). Unfortunately, it is unclear whether this means only Qt threads or Python base threads.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, signals can only be attached to QObjects so it means QThreads only.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this correctly.

The first is to use a QThread instead of a python thread. You can then use Qt signals to pass a message back from the `fil` thread to the Qt MainThread and append the message to the `QLineEdit` there. Another similar approach is to continue using a Python thread, but place your message in a Python `Queue.Queue()` object. This `Queue` is then read by a secondary QThread, whose sole purpose is to read messages out of the `Queue` and emit a signal back to the MainThread.

The common feature of these two methods is that you only access Qt GUI objects from the MainThread and use signals/slots to communicate between threads. Here are some other questions where I've answered similar questions (you should be able to adapt them to your program):

- [Redirecting stdout and stderr to a PyQt4 QTextEdit from a secondary thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071448/redirecting-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-pyqt4-qtextedit-from-a-secondary-thread)
- [Syncing activity in PyQt QThreads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004298/syncing-activity-in-pyqt-qthreads)

However, since answering those questions, my colleagues and I have created a project that helps simplify writing multi-threaded Qt applications. The project is called *[qtutils](https://bitbucket.org/philipstarkey/qtutils)* and is on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qtutils/) so it can be installed with pip or easy_install (just run `pip install qtutils` or `easy_install qtutils` from a commandline/terminal window).

This library has (among others) some functions `inmain` and `inmain_later` which will run a specified method in the Qt MainThread (regardless of the thread the call is made from) synchronously or asynchronously. Documentation on how to use these methods is [here](https://bitbucket.org/philipstarkey/qtutils/wiki/invoke_in_main). I've modified your example code to use my inmain method and put the code here: http://pastebin.com/QM1Y6zBx -- obviously you need to install *qtutils* for it to work!