# Replotting graph based on ROS subscribed data

Tags: python, pyqt, ros, qwt

**Architecture**

I have a plot. And a curve in that plot.
I have a node in the file and a subscriber. This subscriber subscribes to some float data, that is being published.
Every time some data is published, I update the curve by adding the new datapoint to the existing set.

**Problem**

The graph is not updated properly. As the data comes in every second, the GUI is getting hanged up and after some time, the GUI is aborted due to a Segmentation Fault.

**Code**

```
def initUI(self):

    # x11.XInitThreads()

    # xlib.XInitThreads()

    # initialising the window

    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

    # self.setGeometry(300, 300, 160, 1000)
    # self.setWindowTitle('Visualizer')

    # main layout

    self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

    # Creating the elements in this widget

    a = QtGui.QLabel("Navigation", self)

    a.setStyleSheet("QLabel{ background-color: white; color: black; font-size: 25px; }")

    self.plot = Qwt.QwtPlot(self)
    self.plot.setCanvasBackground(Qt.black)
    self.plot.setAxisTitle(Qwt.QwtPlot.xBottom, 'Time')
    self.plot.setAxisScale(Qwt.QwtPlot.xBottom, 0, 10, 1)
    self.plot.setAxisTitle(Qwt.QwtPlot.yLeft, 'Temperature')
    self.plot.setAxisScale(Qwt.QwtPlot.yLeft, 0, 250, 40)
    self.plot.replot()

    self.curve = Qwt.QwtPlotCurve('')
    self.curve.setRenderHint(Qwt.QwtPlotItem.RenderAntialiased)
    pen = QPen(QColor('limegreen'))
    pen.setWidth(2)
    self.curve.setPen(pen)
    self.curve.attach(self.plot)

    self.layout.addWidget(a)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.plot)

def listener(self):       

    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)

    rospy.Subscriber(TOPIC_NAME, String, self.callback)

def callback(self, data):

    self.xData.append(self.counter + 1)
    self.yData.append(int(str(data.data)))
    self.counter += 1

    self.curve.setData(self.xData, self.yData)
    self.plot.replot()
```

Calling these functions :-

```
self.listener()
self.initUI()
```

Once the listener is called, the subscriber is automatically associated with the callback function. The callback function looks at the new data, adds it to the y-axis and then, replots the graph.

**Error**

I am getting this error everytime a new datapoint is published :-

```
QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents: Cannot send posted events for objects in another thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::setBrush: Painter not active
QPainter::drawRects: Painter not active
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::translate: Painter not active
QPainter::save: Painter not active
QPainter::setRenderHint: Painter must be active to set rendering hints
QPainter::save: Painter not active
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore
QPainter::restore: Unbalanced save/restore
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

I don't understand this error.

**About the publisher**

ROS follows the [Publisher-Subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) pattern. I have already created a node that publishes a random integer. This integer should be plotted on the graph.

**Specifications**

```
Ubuntu 12.04
ROS Hydro
PyQt4
Qwt5
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `callback` method is running in thread. You cannot update Qt GUI objects from another thread. This is why you see errors and get segfaults.

The solutions are:

- In the callback, append the data to a list. Use a `QTimer` started from the main thread to periodically check the list for updates and replot the graph (not an ideal solutions, but will likely get the job done)
- In the callback, place the data in a python `Queue.Queue()`. Have a `QThread` block on reading from this queue and emit a qt signal (with the data in it) each time something is read from the `Queue`. Connect a method in your main thread to this qt signal. Your method in the main thread thus gets the data and can update the plot from the main thread.

Here are a bunch of other stack overflow questions which do something similar (send data from a thread into the qt main thread to avoid segfaults) or will be useful when delving into multithreaded pyqt applications:

- [Redirecting stdout and stderr to a PyQt4 QTextEdit from a secondary thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071448/redirecting-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-pyqt4-qtextedit-from-a-secondary-thread)
- [PyQt: moveToThread does not work when using partial() for slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317195/pyqt-movetothread-does-not-work-when-using-partial-for-slot)
- [PyQt: Connecting a signal to a slot to start a background operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752154/pyqt-connecting-a-signal-to-a-slot-to-start-a-background-operation)