# How come the main thread is blocked if .connect takes a lambda function?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm trying to let a button spin up a new thread that does nothing but sleep for 30 seconds. However, the main thread is blocked if the slot is a lambda function. Does anyone know why this is the case and not behaving what I was expecting it to be? Here's my code:

```
    # ...
    def setup(self):
        # ...
        self.pushButton_TestConnection.clicked.connect(self.process)

    def process(self):
        self.worker_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
        self.worker_thread.started.connect(lambda: self.worker.sleep(30))

        self.worker_thread.start()

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    def sleep(self, secs):
        time.sleep(secs)
```

It works fine with the following

```
     self.worker_thread.started.connect(self.worker.sleep)

        self.worker_thread.start()

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    def sleep(self):
        time.sleep(30)
```

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23317195/1994235

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Qt the thread in which code is executed is determined by the [thread affinity](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#qobject-and-threads) of the object receiving a signal. If you call a objects method directly from a different thread, it will be executed in the calling thread, no matter the thread affinity of the called object.

Lambdas and other python callables do not have a thread affinity (they're not QObjects after all, it's just a nice feature of PyQt allowing you to connect a signal to any python callable), so they will always be executed in the main (GUI) thread.
So in this case the lambda is executed in the GUI thread, so the `worker.sleep` call will also be executed there and will block it until the call returns.

To make this work, you need to connect the `started` signal directly to a slot of the Worker object, or communicate with the Worker using a signal you emit from the lambda.