# PySide: method is not executed in thread context if method is invoked via lambda

Tags: python, lambda, pyside, qthread

I have a `Worker` object and use its method `moveToThread` to put it in a thread.

Now i call its `work` method:

- If I invoke the method directly, it is executed in the thread its object is living in
- If I invoke the method using lambda, the method is executed in the main thread

Example:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys

class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def work(self):
        print(self.thread().currentThread())


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btnInThread = QPushButton('in thread')
        self.btnNotInThread = QPushButton('not in thread')
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.btnInThread)
        layout.addWidget(self.btnNotInThread)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.worker = Worker()
        self.Thread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.Thread)
        self.Thread.start()

        self.btnInThread.clicked.connect(self.worker.work)
        self.btnNotInThread.clicked.connect(lambda: self.worker.work())

        self.show()
        print('{0} <- Main Thread'.format(self.thread().currentThread()))


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have done excessive testing (see code in snippet) but i have absolutly no idea what's going on.

**So my question is:**

Why is `work` executed in the main thread and not the thread its object lives in if it is invoked with `lambda`? And most important what can i do if i want to call a method of `Worker` requiring arguments where i cant spare the `lambda`?

```js
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
from time import sleep
import functools
import sys


class Worker(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def work(self, name='Nothing'):
        print('Thread ID: {1} - {0} start'.format(name, QThread.currentThreadId()))
        sleep(1)
        print('##### End {0}'.format(name))


class HackPushButton(QPushButton):
    clicked_with_arg = Signal(str)
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.argument = None
        self.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicked_with_arg.emit(self.argument))


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.buttonWithoutLambda = QPushButton('[Works] Call work() without arguments and without lambda')
        self.buttonWithLambda = QPushButton('[Blocks] Call work() with arguments and with lambda')
        self.buttonWithFunctools = QPushButton('[Blocks] Call work() with arguments and with functools')
        self.buttonWithHelperFunctionWithArgument = QPushButton('[Blocks] Call work() with arguments and with helper function')
        self.buttonWithHelperFunctionWithoutArgument = QPushButton('[Blocks] Call work() without arguments and with helper function')
        self.buttonWithHack = HackPushButton('[Works] Call work() with arguments via dirty hack')
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonWithoutLambda)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonWithLambda)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonWithFunctools)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonWithHelperFunctionWithArgument)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonWithHelperFunctionWithoutArgument)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonWithHack)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.Worker = Worker()
        self.Thread = QThread()
        self.Worker.moveToThread(self.Thread)
        self.Thread.start()

        # Doesn't block GUI
        self.buttonWithoutLambda.clicked.connect(self.Worker.work)

        # Blocks GUI
        self.buttonWithLambda.clicked.connect(lambda: self.Worker.work('Lambda'))

        # Blocks GUI
        self.buttonWithFunctools.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.Worker.work, 'Functools'))

        # Blocks GUI
        self.helperFunctionArgument = 'Helper function without arguments'
        self.buttonWithHelperFunctionWithArgument.clicked.connect(self.helperFunctionWithArgument)

        # Blocks GUI
        self.buttonWithHelperFunctionWithoutArgument.clicked.connect(self.helperFunctionWithoutArgument)

        # Doesn't block GUI
        self.buttonWithHack.argument = 'Hack'
        self.buttonWithHack.clicked_with_arg.connect(self.Worker.work)

        print('Thread ID: {0}'.format(QThread.currentThreadId()))
        self.show()

    def helperFunctionWithArgument(self):
        self.Worker.work(self.helperFunctionArgument)

    def helperFunctionWithoutArgument(self):
        self.Worker.work()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: My impression of threads was that the code had to be in the run method in order to be running in the thread. Otherwise I feel like the code should always be in main especially since you are triggering `work` from a signal. I thought that signals always ran code in the main thread unless you set the signal up to use a direct connection. I'm on Windows with Python 3.4 PySide 1.2.2 and your code just crashes, so I can't be of much help.

Comment: i updated my code. doesn't crash under windows anymore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt: moveToThread does not work when using partial() for slot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317195/pyqt-movetothread-does-not-work-when-using-partial-for-slot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have an answer.

I tried you code and and changed the `connect` method for clicked to use a `QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection` and `QtCore.Qt.DirectConnection` (`connect(self.worker.work, Qt.QueuedConnection)`). The Direct connection makes both functions work the same way (the way that lambda works) they both run in the main thread. However, the Queued connection makes them work differently. The lambda function still runs in the main thread while the worker function call runs in the separate thread. Note: without giving an argument in `connect` you are using AutoConnection which will use the QueuedConnection.

I read through the documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads.

> Queued Connection The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. The slot is executed in the receiver's thread.

So I believe that lambda is running in the main thread, because lambda is creating a new function. The new lambda function is not a slot and exists in the main thread. The lambda functions receiver's thread is the main thread. Meanwhile the `worker.work` method is a slot that has a different receiver thread. So the signal knows to call `self.worker.work` in the worker thread while it calls the lambda function in the main thread which then calls `self.worker.work()` in the main thread.

I know this is inconvenient, because lambda is useful for passing arguments to a function.

**Use Signal Mapper to Pass Values**

```
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui
import sys
import time


def create_map(obj, func, args=None):
    """Create a signal mapper to associate a value with a function.

    Args:
        obj (QObject): Object to map the value to with the signal mapper
        func (function): Function to run when the signal mapper.map function is called.
        args (tuple)[None]: Arguments you want to pass to the function.

    Returns:
        map_callback (function): Map function to connect to a signal.
        mapper (QSignalMapper): You may need to keep a reference of the signal mapper object.
    """
    mapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper()
    mapper.setMapping(obj, args)
    mapper.mapped.connect(func)
    return mapper.map, mapper


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def work(self, value=0):
        print(self.thread().currentThread())
        time.sleep(2)
        print("end", value)


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btnInThread = QtGui.QPushButton('in thread')
        self.btnNotInThread = QtGui.QPushButton('not in thread')
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.btnInThread)
        layout.addWidget(self.btnNotInThread)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.worker = Worker()
        self.Thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.Thread)
        self.Thread.start()

        self.btnInThread.clicked.connect(self.worker.work)

        # Use a signal mapper
        # self.mapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper()
        # self.mapper.setMapping(self.btnNotInThread, 1)
        # self.mapper.mapped.connect(self.worker.work)
        # self.btnNotInThread.clicked.connect(self.mapper.map)

        # Alternative mapper method from above
        callback, self.mapper = create_map(self.btnNotInThread, self.worker.work, 1)
        self.btnNotInThread.clicked.connect(callback)

        self.show()
        print('{0} <- Main Thread'.format(self.thread().currentThread()))


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```