# How to start several threads from methods?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread

I am trying to port an application I wrote in `Tkinter` to `PyQt`. The application has several threads which query external information (via APIs) and use it to update text labels in the application. There is no user interaction.

In `Tkinter` I was using the `after()` method. In `PyQT`, as far as I understand, I should use `QtCore.QThread()`.

The following example program is supposed to update two labels (`hour` and `minute`). The UI is generated from Qt Designer and is basically the two text labels above. I see in the app window that the hours are updated (they change in the GUI and `"update hour"` is printed on the console). The minutes are not. My (failed) understanding was that `started.connect()` was there to fire up a thread with the indicated method. It looks like it works only once.

How should I change the code so that a thread is started for each of the methods in `UpdateTime`?

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from infoscren_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class Infoscreen(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)


class UpdateTime(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, root):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self.root = root

    def UpdateHour(self):
        hour = 0
        while True:
            hour += 1
            print("update hour")
            self.root.hour.setText(str(hour))
            time.sleep(1)

    def UpdateMinute(self):
        minute = 0
        while True:
            minute += 2
            print("update minute")
            self.root.minute.setText(str(minute))
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    infoscreen = Infoscreen()
    thread = QtCore.QThread()

    obj = UpdateTime(infoscreen)
    obj.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(obj.UpdateHour)
    thread.started.connect(obj.UpdateMinute)
    thread.finished.connect(app.exit)
    thread.start()

    infoscreen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run both `UpdateHour` and `UpdateMinute` in the same thread, because the first one to start will just block the other one. If you want to run two blocking loops like that, each one will require its own thread.

Also, it is not thread-safe to directly call GUI methods from outside the main GUI thread (i.e. the one in which the application first starts). Instead, you should define custom signals to be emitted from the worker threads:

```
class UpdateHours(QtCore.QObject):
    hourChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def updateHour(self):
        ...
        self.hourChanged.emit(hour)
```

Objects in the main thread can then connect to these signals and update the GUI from there:

```
    self.hourObject.hourChanged.connect(self.handleHourChanged)
    ...

    def handleHourChanged(self, hour):
       # do something with hour value...
```

By default, when the sender and receiver are in different threads, Qt will automatically ensure that the signals are processed asynchronously (they are added to the application's event queue), which is enough to guarantee thread-safety.

Comment: Thank you. There is still one thing I do not understand: how are the methods of the object (`updateHour` in your example) moved to the thread via `.moveToThread(thread)` started? Are all of the methods in this object started by default? I do not see any mention of them in neither your code, nor Schollii's one?

Comment: @WoJ. Using the threads' `started` signal as in your original example seems most natural. It would probably be wise to decorate those methods as slots, though (updated my answer in view of that).

Answer (score 1):

The GUI runs in the main thread; that's where app.exec() is called. QThread instances you create represent "secondary" threads. Never call a method of a QObject (like `QLabel.setText`) from a non-main thread. Instead, define custom signals on the class that you move to the secondary thread, and connect them to slots of your GUI objects. Then PyQt takes care of calling the slot in the main thread, even if the signal is emitted from a secondary thread. Naively implemented, this would look something like this:

```
class UpdateTime(QtCore.QObject):
    sig_minute = pyqtSignal(str)
    sig_hour = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

    def UpdateHour(self):
        hour = 0
        while True:
            hour += 1
            print("update hour")
            self.sig_hour.emit(str(hour))
            time.sleep(1)

    def UpdateMinute(self):
        minute = 0
        while True:
            minute += 2
            print("update minute")
            self.sig_minute.emit(str(minute))
            time.sleep(1)
```

You could establish the connections in main:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    infoscreen = Infoscreen()
    thread = QtCore.QThread()

    obj = UpdateTime()
    obj.moveToThread(thread)
    obj.sig_hour.connect(infoscreen.hour.setText)
    obj.sig_minute.connect(infoscreen.minute.setText)
    thread.finished.connect(app.exit)
    thread.start()

    infoscreen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note how this has decoupled `InfosSreen` from `UpdateTime`. One could also establish the connections in `InfoScreen.__init__` instead: better encapsulation since the `hour` and `minute` labels are members of `InfoScreen`. Or one could establish the connections in `UpdateTime.__init__`, but in Qt it seems the philosophy is for the visuals to know about the workers (logic, controllers, etc) rather than the other way around.

In any case, it is important for the connections to be established after the `moveToThread`: although the default connection type is AUTO, this just means that at the time the connection is made, Qt will determine which type of connection to establish (blocking or queued). So if you connect `InfoScreen` to `UpdateTime` before `moveToThread`, then Qt thinks they "live" in the same thread and makes the connection "blocking". Even after `moveToThread` is called, the connection remains blocking, so a signal emitted by a function executing in secondary thread causes the connected slot from `InfosScreen` to be called in the same thread rather than in the main thread. If on the other hand the `UpdateTime` is first moved to thread, *then* connected, Qt knows it is in a non-main thread, so makes the connection queued. In that case, emitting a signal in secondary thread will cause the connected slot to be called in the main thread.

However the above won't do anything because moving an object to a thread does not "run" the object. What runs is the thread's event loop, once `QThread.start()` is called. So to have the object do some work, you have to call a slot on your object, such that the slot executes in the secondary thread. One way is via the `start` signal of the thread, connected after `moveToThread`:

```
thread.started.connect(obj.run)
```

Then eventhough the `QThread` instance lives in the main thread, its `started` signal will be handled in the secondary thread, asynchronously. The `obj.run` method can call the `UpdateHour` and `UpdateMinute` as appropriate. However, your `UpdateHour` and `UpdateMinute` cannot both be looping indefinitely (using `while True`) in the same thread. You would either have to create two separate objects living in two separate threads, one for hour and one for minute, or make the two updates cooperate by running for only small chunk of time. The details depend on what functionality you are porting from TK, but for example of latter approach, it could look like this:

```
class UpdateTime(QtCore.QObject):
    sig_minute = pyqtSignal(str)
    sig_hour = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.hour = 0
        self.minute = 0
        self.seconds = 0

    def run(self):
        while True:
           time.sleep(1)
           self.seconds += 1
           self.UpdateMinute()
           self.UpdateHour()

    def UpdateHour(self):
        if self.minute == 60: 
            self.hour += 1
            print("update hour")
            self.sig_minute.emit(str(self.hour))
            self.minute = 0

    def UpdateMinute(self):
        if self.seconds == 60: 
            self.minute += 1
            print("update minute")
            self.sig_minute.emit(str(self.minute))
            self.seconds = 0
```

Instead of connecting the `started` signal to call the `obj.run`, you could connect a `QTimer`'s `timeout` signal instead, in single shot mode, so that `obj.run` gets called once, at some later time. Or connect a button's `clicked` signal, to start it only when a button clicked. In your case the `UpdateTime` could also be implemented by calling [`QObject.startTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#startTimer) and overriding `eventTimer` to increase minute by 1. See [Qt timers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/timers.html) for more info on timers.

Not tested the above for bugs, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - would you mind expanding a bit? What is the "main thread"? Is it the one launched via `app.exec_()`? How should I launch the worker threads so that they can send appropriate signals (to the main thread - I assume), the way I tried in my code does not work (only the first one is launched)?

Comment: With auto-connection, the connection type is determined when the signal is emitted, not when it is connected. So long as the receiver is either a Qt slot, or a python callable that has been decorated with `@QtCore.pyqtSlot`, the connection can be made at any time.

Comment: @Schollii: Thank you for expanding your initial answer, this clarifies a lot. I have the same question as to ekhumoro: how are the methods of the object (`updateHour` and `updateMinute`) moved to the thread via `.moveToThread(thread)` started? Are all of the methods in this object started by default?

Comment: OK, i got it - I need to start all the threads for the methods via `thread.started.connect(obj.<method of obj>)`

Comment: Also; shouldn't the signal be defined as `pyqtSignal(str)`?

Comment: Yes. I added some info although it looks like you figured it out in the meantime, good job! Yes the pyqtSignal data is of type str, fixed.

Comment: @ekhumoro What I have observed is that if I establish connections before `moveToThread`, the connections are synchronous even after the `moveToThread`, whereas if I establish connections after the `moveToThread`, they are automatically asynchronous. However, I don't use `@pyqtSlot`, maybe that's why.

Comment: @Schollii. Yes, it's because of the `@pyqtSlot`: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20818401/984421).