# PyQt signals between threads not emitted

Tags: multithreading, qt, pyqt, signals-slots, worker

I am stuck. It should be easy and I have done it many times using the C++ API of Qt however for some reason several of my signals/slots are not working when I'm doing this in PyQt (I've recently started with the concept of a worker `QObject` in PyQt). I believe it has to do something with the separate thread I'm emitting my signals to/from.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel

class Slave(QObject):

  countSignal = pyqtSignal(int)

  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(Slave, self).__init__()

    self.toggleFlag = False
    self.counter = 0

  @pyqtSlot()
  def work(self):
    if not self.toggleFlag: return

    if self.counter > 10: self.counter = 0
    self.counter += self.counter
    self.countSignal.emit(self.counter)

  @pyqtSlot()
  def toggle(self):
    self.toggleFlag = not self.toggleFlag


class Master(QWidget):

  toggleSignal = pyqtSignal()

  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(Master, self).__init__()

    self.initUi()
    self.setupConn()

  def __del__(self):
    self.thread.quit()
    while not self.thread.isFinished(): pass

  def initUi(self):
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.buttonToggleSlave = QPushButton('Start')
    self.labelCounterSlave = QLabel('0')
    layout.addWidget(self.buttonToggleSlave)
    layout.addWidget(self.labelCounterSlave)
    self.setLayout(layout)
    self.show()

  def setupConn(self):
    self.thread = QThread()
    slave = Slave()
    timer = QTimer()
    timer.setInterval(100)

    # Make sure that both objects are removed properly once the thread is terminated
    self.thread.finished.connect(timer.deleteLater)
    self.thread.finished.connect(slave.deleteLater)

    # Connect the button to the toggle slot of this widget
    self.buttonToggleSlave.clicked.connect(self.toggle)
    # Connect widget's toggle signal (emitted from inside widget's toggle slot) to slave's toggle slot
    self.toggleSignal.connect(slave.toggle)

    # Connect timer's timeout signal to slave's work slot
    timer.timeout.connect(slave.work)
    timer.timeout.connect(self.timeout)
    # Connect slave's countSignal signal to widget's viewCounter slot
    slave.countSignal.connect(self.viewCounter)

    # Start timer
    timer.start()
    # Move timer and slave to thread
    timer.moveToThread(self.thread)
    slave.moveToThread(self.thread)

    # Start thread
    self.thread.start()    

  @pyqtSlot(int)
  def viewCounter(self, value):
    print(value)
    self.labelCounterSlave.setText(str(value))

  @pyqtSlot()
  def toggle(self):
    print("Toggle called")
    self.buttonToggleSlave.setText("Halt" if (self.buttonToggleSlave.text() == "Start") else "Start")
    self.toggleSignal.emit()

  @pyqtSlot()
  def timeout(self):
    print("Tick")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    w = Master()
    w.setStyleSheet('cleanlooks')
    app.exec_()
```

Following things are not triggered/emitted:

- `timeout()` slot of my widget - I added this to see why the timer is not triggering my worker's slot but all I found out is that it doesn't work here either...
- `work()` and `toggle()` slots inside my `Slave` worker class
- `countSignal` - it is never emitted since my widget's `viewCounter()` slot is never triggered

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I have connected the signals and slots, started my timer, moved it along with the worker to my separate thread and started the thread.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with the code that are preventing it from working correctly.

1. As per the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#details), you must start (and stop) a timer from the thread it resides in. You cannot start it from another thread. If you want to have the timer reside in the thread, you should relocate the instantiation code to the `Slave` object and call `timer.start()` in a slot connected to the threads `started` signal. You do need to be careful here though as the `Slave.__init__` method is going to still run in the main thread. Alternatively, you could just leave the timer in the main thread.
2. `slave` and `timer` are being garbage collected when `setupConn()` has finished. Store them as `self.slave` and `self.timer`. (Alternatively you should be able to specify a parent for them, but this seems to result in app crashes on exit so it's probably best to stick to storing them as instance attributes).
3. I assume the line `self.counter += self.counter` should really be `self.counter += 1`? Otherwise the counter is never incremented :)

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about the timer. That was the major problem here. As for the increment...(facepalm)...Yeap, it is never incremented :D Btw for the `self.slave` and `self:timer` I also thought it was going out of scope however I am so used to the C++ version, where you are passing a pointer to the thread of those two that I didn't think to change this here. I have one question though - in C++ it is incorrect to create things as class members if you are going to move these to another thread. I guess this isn't the case in Python? Doesn't this render `QObject.deleteLater()` pointless?

Comment: @rbaleksandar It might not be good practice (although I'm not sure what the alternative would be) but there is nothing fundamentally wrong with doing it in Python. It's just a reference to a c++ object. `deleteLater()` should still work, and if you try and access the Qt object after it is deleted through the remaining reference, you will get a warning printed to the terminal about the underlying c++ object being deleted.

Comment: In C++ if you use a class member it will (I can't remember correctly right now which of the following will happen) either fail or the signals will not be properly done and you will end up emitting/capturing in the wrong thread. That's why I went without the `self` but then again passing arguments in Python works a little bit differently from what we have in C++ (in terms of controlling whether it's passed by reference or value). If slave and timer are part of the widget's class (in my case) then once the widget's destroyed it should also destroy all its members including these two. Hmmm...

Comment: @rbaleksandar for Python, when the Python widget class is garbage collected the Python pointers to the c++ objects will be deleted but the c++ objects themselves will only be garbage collected if nothing else holds a reference to them and they don't have a parent as far as Qt is concerned. I think as long as you consider the Qt c++ object and Python references as only losely coupled, you'll be able to see what works and what doesn't. In terms of signal connection with objects in threads, this might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20752154/1994235

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the linked page. Reading it right now.