# How do I connect a PyQt5 slot to a signal function in a class?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, signals-slots, qobject

I'm trying to set up a pyqt signal between a block of UI code and a separate python class that is just for handling event responses.  I don't want to give the UI code access to the handler (classic MVC style).  Unfortunately, I am having difficulty connecting the slot to the signal.  Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject

class UiClass(QObject):
    mySignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal( str )
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
    def send_signal(self):
        self.mySignal.emit("Hello world!")

class HandlerClass():
    currentMessage = "none"
    def register(self, mySignal):
        mySignal.connect(self.receive_signal)        
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def receive_signal(self, message):
        self.currentMessage = message
        print(message)

ui = UiClass()
handler = HandlerClass()
handler.register(ui.mySignal)
ui.send_signal()
```

When I run this code it fails at the handler.register line.  Here is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\git\IonControl\testpyqtslot.py", line 25, in
>
> handler.register(ui.mySignal)
>
> File "C:\git\IonControl\testpyqtslot.py", line 17, in register
>
> mySignal.connect(self.receive_signal)
>
> TypeError: connect() failed between UiClass.mySignal[str] and receive_signal()

I'd like this code to successfully register the signal to the slot and have the handler print "hello world" at the end.  What did I do wrong here?

My basic question is this: how do I connect a signal to a slot function that is part of a class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error happens becuase you are using `pyqtSlot` decorator in a class which doesn't inherit from `QObject`. You can fix the problem by either getting rid of the decorator, or making `HandlerClass` a subclass of `QObject`.

The main purpose of `pyqtSlot` is to allow several different overloads of a slot to be defined, each with a different signature. It may also be needed sometimes when making cross-thread connections. However, these use-cases are relatively rare, and in most PyQt applications it is not necessary to use `pyqtSlot` at all. Signals can be connected to **any** python callable object, whether it is decorated as a slot or not.

Comment: I made HandlerClass a subclass of QObject and it works beautifully.  Thanks!

Comment: When is this needed for cross-thread connections? Always? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @DavidPärsson. Don't know whether it's documented, but see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20818401/984421) for one scenario where it may be needed.