# Why does input() cause "QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running"?

Tags: python, multithreading, input, pyqt4, qcoreapplication

I have run into this QCoreApplication problem where invoking input() after a QObject finishes executing inside a QThread causes an infinite loop printing to the console "QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running".

In the code I create a generic worker as a QObject, move it into a QThread (the sanctioned way to use QThread, instead of subclassing it) and then execute another QObject's (Master class) function inside the generic worker. Everything works fine as long as I don't call input() after the Master has been executed. Note that the problem occurs also if I execute a function directly in the worker (not a Master instance's function).

Here is the sample code to reproduce the problem:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot


class Worker(QObject):
    """
    Generic worker.
    """
    start = pyqtSignal(str)
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, function):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self._function = function
        self.start.connect(self.run)

    def run(self):
        self._function()
        self.finished.emit()


class Master(QObject):
    """
    An object that will use the worker class.
    """
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def do(self):
        print("Do what?")
        self.finished.emit()


def done():
    # FIXME This will cause an infinite loop printing to the console:
    # "QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running"
    input("Enter your answer: ")


def main():
    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    master = Master()
    worker = Worker(master.do)
    master.finished.connect(done)

    thread = QThread()
    thread.started.connect(worker.run)
    worker.moveToThread(thread)

    # Terminating thread gracefully, or so.
    worker.finished.connect(thread.quit)
    worker.finished.connect(worker.deleteLater)
    thread.finished.connect(thread.deleteLater)

    thread.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no real problem with `input` in your example. After pressing enter in `done()`, control will return to the event-loop and then wait for further user interaction - which is the normal and expected behaviour.

You don't make it clear what you expect to happen after that. But if you want the program to quit, just do this:

```
def done():
    input("Enter your answer: ")
    QCoreApplication.quit()
```

The Qt warning message is harmless, but it can be removed like this:

```
def main():
    from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtRemoveInputHook
    pyqtRemoveInputHook()

    app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    ...
```

The only real problem in your example is the threading implementation. If you add the line `print(QThread.currentThread())` to `Worker.run()`, `Master.do()` and `main()`, you will see that all three are executed in the *main thread*. This is because you connected the `thread.start` signal *before* moving the worker to the other thread. The best (i.e. most easily maintainable) way to fix this issue to always use the `@pyqtSlot` decorator on any slots that are connected across threads - because then it won't matter when the signal connections are made. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818401/984421) for a more complete explanation of this issue).

Comment: Excellent! I solved 2 issues with your answer. Thanks a lot.