# "QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running" except when stopping code at sys.exit(app.exec_())

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, event-loop

I'm new to Qt and PyQt and I'm trying to connect an elaborate file parsing library written by someone else to a simple GUI. When I click on the "Process Data" button, I encounter the following error message repeatedly:

```bash
QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running
QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running
QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running
QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running
QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running
...
```

I have noticed that when I debug the script, the issue doesn't occur if I put a breakpoint on the line `sys.exit(app.exec_())` and only click on "Resume" after selecting the data. In this specific case, if I do this once and press "Resume" the program works in all subsequent attempts to load file(s) and folders.

Here is the relevant code:

```py
import os
import sys
import traceback
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QTextEdit)

def ParsingFunction(directory=None, files=[], d_dataAlreadyIn=None):
# ...

# Import/outport function, mostly used for loading the .med files
from DC_Lib import DC_IO_lib 
from DC_Lib import DC_CV_Processing 
from DC_Lib import DC_IV_Processing

class DataProcessingApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...
        self.process_button = QPushButton("Process Data")
        self.process_button.clicked.connect(self.process_data)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.process_button)
        # ...

    def process_data(self):
        if self.directory or self.files:
            self.text_edit.append("Processing data...")
            if self.directory:
                self.data = ParsingFunction(directory=self.directory)
            else:
                self.data = ParsingFunction(files=self.files)

            self.text_edit.append("Data processing complete.")
        else:
            self.text_edit.append("Please select a directory or files to process.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DataProcessingApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If the question is too vague let me know, but I think this behavior with the `exec_()` method during debugging might ring a bell to someone with more experience with Qt. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

### [update]

To improve reproducibility here are the contents of the ParsingFunction and its subfunctions. I won't add more code because I'm pretty sure the problem is with the `input()` call in  `GetMeDopingType()`:

```py
while True:
   inp = str(input())
   if inp.strip()[0].upper() == "C":
      C_IO.Abort()
   if inp.strip()[0].lower() == 'n' or inp.strip()[0].lower() == 'p':
      break
   GLOBAL_d_Dopingtypes[wafername] = inp.strip()[0].lower()
```

When I hardcode `inp`, I don't get the `QCoreApplication::exec`. Any ideas why not? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40177743/why-does-input-cause-qcoreapplicationexec-the-event-loop-is-already-runnin) sounds like it has to do with my issue, but I haven't been able to translate into a fix for my case.

Here's the full code:

```py
def ParsingFunction(directory=None, files=[], d_dataAlreadyIn=None):
    AllData = {}
    if d_dataAlreadyIn is not None:
        AllData = d_dataAlreadyIn
    WarnCount = 0

    if directory is not None:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
            for filename in files:
                WorkMagic_SubFunction(C_IO.EndInSlash(root), filename, AllData)
                WarnCount += 1
                if WarnCount % 100 == 0:
                    print(filename)
                if WarnCount > 10000:
                    print("Warning: " + str(WarnCount) + " files processed, could indicate an infinite loop!")
    else:
        for file in files:
            root = os.path.dirname(file)
            filename = os.path.basename(file)
            WorkMagic_SubFunction(C_IO.EndInSlash(root), filename, AllData)
            WarnCount += 1
            if WarnCount % 100 == 0:
                print(filename)
            if WarnCount > 10000:
                print("Warning: " + str(WarnCount) + " files processed, could indicate an infinite loop!")

    return AllData


def WorkMagic_SubFunction(directory, filename, AllData):
    global DotArea
    global ExtentionToLookFor
    global INFER_PMA_FROM_FOLDER

    extention = filename.split('.')[-1]
    if extention == ExtentionToLookFor:
        tmp = C_IO.ReadInMedFile(directory + filename, ForceReadSecondDataSection=HasToHandleBTI)
        mestype = FigureOutWhatThisIs(tmp)
        if 'SiP' in filename:
            tmp["techinfo"]["doping"] = 'P'
        if mestype == "DropThisOne":
            return AllData
        if INFER_PMA_FROM_FOLDER and "_PMA" in directory:
            tmp["techinfo"]["wafer"] = tmp["techinfo"]["wafer"] + "A"
        Device_ID = tmp["techinfo"]["testchip"] + "-" + tmp["techinfo"]["testdevice"]
        if not "DotArea" in tmp["techinfo"]:
            guessarr = FilenameToArea(filename)
            if guessarr is None:
                tmp["techinfo"]["DotArea"] = str(DotArea)
            else:
                tmp["techinfo"]["DotArea"] = str(guessarr)
        else:
            tmp["techinfo"]["DotArea"] = str(tmp["techinfo"]["DotArea"])
        tmp["techinfo"]["ScriptName"] = str(SCRIPTNAME)
        tmp["techinfo"]["ScriptVersion"] = str(VERSION)
        if "devicemap" in tmp["techinfo"]:
            tmp["techinfo"]["devicemap"] = tmp["techinfo"]["devicemap"].replace(r"/imec/other/drec/medusa", r"\\unix\drec\medusa")
        if "chipmap" in tmp["techinfo"]:
            tmp["techinfo"]["chipmap"] = tmp["techinfo"]["chipmap"].replace(r"/imec/other/drec/medusa", r"\\unix\drec\medusa")
        key = tmp["techinfo"]["wafer"] + "___###____" + tmp["techinfo"]["chuck_temperature"]
        if not key in AllData:
            AllData[key] = {}
        if not mestype in AllData[key]:
            AllData[key][mestype] = {}
        if not Device_ID in AllData[key][mestype]:
            AllData[key][mestype][Device_ID] = []
        finalStruct = None
        if not (mestype == "NBTI" or mestype == "PBTI"):
            if HasToHandleBTI:
                techinfo = tmp["techinfo"]

                # call to the input()
                dop = GetMeDopingType(techinfo["wafer"], techinfo)

                techinfo['doping'] = dop
                tmp = C_IO.ReadInMedFile(directory + filename, ForceReadSecondDataSection=False)
                tmp["techinfo"] = techinfo
        if mestype == "MFCV":
            finalStruct = tmp
        elif mestype == "Hys":
            TheStruct = C_CV.CV_HYS_Curve(SampleName=tmp["techinfo"]["wafer"], DopingType=GetMeDopingType(tmp["techinfo"]["wafer"], tmp["techinfo"]), Temperature_K=300)
            TheStruct.Load___read_in_Med_structure(tmp)
            TheStruct.do_areanormalisation(1.0)
            finalStruct = TheStruct
        elif mestype == "NBTI" or mestype == "PBTI":
            TheStruct = C_CV.SFCV()
            TheStruct.Load___read_in_Med_Structure(tmp)
            TheStruct.do_areanormalisation(1.0)
            finalStruct = TheStruct
        elif mestype == "IgVg":
            TheStruct = C_IV.SFIV()
            TheStruct.Load___read_in_Med_Structure(tmp)
            finalStruct = TheStruct
        elif mestype == "CET":
            TheStruct = C_CV.SFCV()
            TheStruct.Load___read_in_Med_Structure(tmp)
            finalStruct = TheStruct
        else:
            print("Mestype not supported! '" + str(mestype) + "' in file:" + directory + filename)
        if not finalStruct is None:
            if not type(finalStruct) is dict:
                dop = GetMeDopingType(tmp["techinfo"]["wafer"], tmp["techinfo"])
                finalStruct._header['doping'] = dop
            AllData[key][mestype][Device_ID].append(finalStruct)
    return AllData

# The function I think is causing the problem
def GetMeDopingType(wafername, techinfo):
    global GLOBAL_d_Dopingtypes
    if "SiP" in wafername:
        return "p"
    if not wafername in GLOBAL_d_Dopingtypes:
        if techinfo is not None and "doping" in techinfo:
            GLOBAL_d_Dopingtypes[wafername] = techinfo["doping"].strip()[0].lower()
        else:
            print("Please prodide doping type for wafer: " + str(wafername) + " [n/p]: ")
            while True:
                inp = str(input())
                if inp.strip()[0].upper() == "C":
                    C_IO.Abort()
                if inp.strip()[0].lower() == 'n' or inp.strip()[0].lower() == 'p':
                    break
            GLOBAL_d_Dopingtypes[wafername] = inp.strip()[0].lower()
    return GLOBAL_d_Dopingtypes[wafername]


def FilenameToArea(filename):
    global ScannedSquareSizes_in_um
    size = None
    for i in ScannedSquareSizes_in_um:
        if "_" + str(i) + "x" + str(i) + "_" in filename:
            size = (float(i) * 1E-4) ** 2
            break
    return size


def FigureOutWhatThisIs(d_info):
    if "targetrole" in d_info["techinfo"]:
        TarRol = d_info["techinfo"]["targetrole"]
        if TarRol == "VFBTEST":
            return "DropThisOne"
        elif TarRol == "CET_EXTRACTION" or TarRol == "REFERENCE":
            return "CET"
        elif TarRol == "FREQ_DISPERSION":
            return "MFCV"
        elif TarRol == "PBTI_MES" or TarRol == "PBTI_Reference" or TarRol == "PBTI_REFERENCE" or TarRol == "PBTI_AFTERCHECK":
            return "PBTI"
        elif TarRol == "NBTI_MES" or TarRol == "NBTI_Reference" or TarRol == "NBTI_REFERENCE" or TarRol == "NBTI_AFTERCHECK":
            return "NBTI"
        elif TarRol == "CVHYS":
            return "Hys"
        elif TarRol == "IgVg_leakage":
            return "IgVg"
        else:
            print("Unknown target role:" + str(TarRol))
            input("just hit enter to continue")
            return "TechniqueNotKnown"
    if "instrument" in d_info["techinfo"]:
        if "Keithley Instruments" in d_info["techinfo"]["instrument"]:
            return "IgVg"
    if "filename" in d_info["techinfo"]:
        tmp = d_info["techinfo"]["filename"]
        if "Vmax" in tmp and not "_f" in tmp:
            return "Hys"
        if not "Vmax" in tmp and "_f" in tmp:
            return "MFCV"
    return "TechniqueNotKnown"
```

Regarding the debugging information I'm using Python 3.7.4 in a venv because part of the project has a dependency on PySide2.

Comment: Sorry but your question is missing important details, most importantly a [mre] which should also include the contents of 'ParsingFunction()`.

Comment: I can edit the code snippet but that function has nothing to do with qt and it calls other functions from the imported modules so I thought it would make the question unnecessarily long. Is there any kind of behavior in the parsing function that you could see causing the event loop error?

Comment: It's impossible to know that without knowing the contents of that function or the purpose/behavior of those imported `DC_Lib` objects. That error can only happen whenever there is an attempt to call `exec()` on a QApplication instance, and we cannot just make assumptions and wild guesses without having an adequate context.

Comment: Also provide debugging details including information on the OS, Python distribution, etc. Did you try to run the code in the terminal, without using an IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input()` function within the `GetMeDopingType()` function seems to cause conflicts with the event loop. When the script is running normally, the event loop is already active, so using `input()` inside it triggers the error.

However, when you add a breakpoint on `sys.exit(app.exec_())` and click "resume" after selecting the data, the event loop hasn't started yet when you reach the `input()` call. That's why it works without any errors in that case.

A solution can be to modify your code to avoid using `input()` within the event loop. Try, for example, to use a separate dialog or input box to gather user input instead of relying on console input.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QApplication

# ...

def GetMeDopingType(wafername, techinfo):
    global GLOBAL_d_Dopingtypes

    if "SiP" in wafername:
        return "p"

    if not wafername in GLOBAL_d_Dopingtypes:
        if techinfo is not None and "doping" in techinfo:
            GLOBAL_d_Dopingtypes[wafername] = techinfo["doping"].strip()[0].lower()
        else:
            app = QApplication.instance()
            dialog = QDialog()
            layout = QVBoxLayout()
            label = QLabel("Please provide doping type for wafer: " + wafername + " [n/p]:")
            input_box = QLineEdit()
            layout.addWidget(label)
            layout.addWidget(input_box)

            ok_button = QPushButton("OK")
            ok_button.clicked.connect(dialog.accept)
            cancel_button = QPushButton("Cancel")
            cancel_button.clicked.connect(app.exit)  # Abort the processing

            layout.addWidget(ok_button)
            layout.addWidget(cancel_button)
            dialog.setLayout(layout)
            dialog.setWindowTitle("Doping Type Input")

            if dialog.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
                inp = input_box.text()
                if inp.strip()[0].upper() == "C":
                    C_IO.Abort()
                GLOBAL_d_Dopingtypes[wafername] = inp.strip()[0].lower()
            else:
                C_IO.Abort()

    return GLOBAL_d_Dopingtypes[wafername]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a PyQt5 bug, where PyQt5 calls the `QCoreApplication::exec()` inside a CPython `PyOS_InputHook` function. That hook causes the `QCoreApplication::exec()` to be called when the `input()` is called or a debug break occurs. (See the function `qtcore_input_hook()` at the `sip/QtCore/qcoreapplication.sip` file in the [PyQt5-5.15.9.tar.gz](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/46/b4b6eae1e24d9432905ef1d4e7c28b6610e28252527cdc38f2a75997d8b5/PyQt5-5.15.9.tar.gz) for details.)

The following demonstrates this hooking.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

app = QCoreApplication([])
def on_timer():
    print('The event loop is running without app.exec()')
QTimer.singleShot(1000, on_timer)
input()

QTimer.singleShot(1000, on_timer)
breakpoint()
```

In PyQt6, the bug was fixed by using the `QEventLoop`.