# PyQt5 Threads, Signal, and Slot. Connect Error

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, signals, slot

I'm new to PyQt5 and I can't seem to connect my pyqtSignal and pyqtSlot. The error, *"TypeError: connect() failed between worker.newIcon[object] and updateIcon()"* pops out. Anyone can guide me to the right path please?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSystemTrayIcon, QAction, QMenu
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot


class worker(QThread):
    newIcon = pyqtSignal(object)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.newIcon.emit(QIcon("shield-off.png"))
            QThread.msleep(1000)


class systemTray():
    def start_tray(self):
        self.app = QApplication([])
        self.app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

        icon = QIcon("shield-on.png")
        self.tray = QSystemTrayIcon()
        self.tray.setIcon(icon)
        self.tray.setVisible(True)

        self.menu = QMenu()
        self.quit = QAction("Exit")
        self.quit.triggered.connect(self.app.quit)
        self.menu.addAction(self.quit)
        self.tray.setContextMenu(self.menu)

        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.newIcon.connect(self.updateIcon)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.thread.start()

        # Run tray
        self.app.exec_()

    @pyqtSlot(object)
    def updateIcon(self, icon):
        self.tray.setIcon(icon)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    be_tray = systemTray()
    be_tray.start_tray()
```

Comment: Please do not use external websites to share code, embed it in your question instead (read how to correctly [format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) and check the syntax and indentetion in the preview before saving changes).

Comment: I am working on the answer: Do you really need two different threads and join them together? What is your goal with this application?

Comment: The worker thread in this example is just an overcomplicated way of implementing a timer. Also, since QIcon is pixmap-based, it doesn't seem to be thread safe. A solution using QTimer would be much simpler, safer and more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pyqtSlot` decorator is intended to be used for `QObject` subclasses, otherwise it will not work correctly.

So, the solution is pretty simple, as you only need to inherit from QObject:

```
class systemTray(QObject):
    def start_tray(self):
        # ...
```

On the other hand, using a `pyqtSlot` decorator is rarely needed and only for specific situations (see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752154/pyqt-connecting-a-signal-to-a-slot-to-start-a-background-operation/20818401#20818401). In your case, it doesn't seem necessary.

Also, since you're already subclassing from QThread, you can just use its own `start()`, without using `moveToThread()` on a new one.