# Why is processEvents() needed to get QThread to work?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, events, pyside

Below is my code for listing all the sub-directories of a directory. I'm using it to understand `QThread` and signal and slots in PySide. The problem is, when I'm not using `Qtcore.QApplication.processEvents()` in the `scan()` method of the `Main` class, the code does not work. Is the event-loop not already running?

```
import sys
import os
import time
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Scanner(QtCore.QObject):
    folderFound = QtCore.Signal(str)
    done = QtCore.Signal()
    def __init__(self, path):
        super(Scanner, self).__init__()
        self.path = path

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def scan(self):
        for folder in os.listdir(self.path):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.folderFound.emit(folder)

class Main(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(420,130)
        self.setWindowTitle('Threads')
        self.lyt = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.lyt)

        self.topLyt = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.lyt.addLayout(self.topLyt)
        self.scanBtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Scan')
        self.scanBtn.clicked.connect(self.scan)
        self.clearBtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Clear')
        self.topLyt.addWidget(self.scanBtn)
        self.topLyt.addWidget(self.clearBtn)

        self.folders = list()

        self.show()

    def scan(self):
        self.th = QtCore.QThread()
        scanner = Scanner(r"D:\\")
        scanner.moveToThread(self.th)

        scanner.folderFound.connect(self.addFolder)
        scanner.done.connect(scanner.deleteLater)
        scanner.done.connect(self.quit)

        self.th.started.connect(scanner.scan)
        self.th.start()

        QtCore.QApplication.processEvents()

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def addFolder(self, folder):
        lbl = QtGui.QLabel(folder)
        self.folders.append(lbl)

        self.lyt.addWidget(lbl)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def quit(self):
        self.th.quit()
        self.th.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()    
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: It  means when I click 'Scan' button, nothing happens, but when I use processEvents, It starts to add folder names in label which it is getting from the thread.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/wiki/ThreadsEventsQObjects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating GUI elements in MultiThreaded PyQT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957195/updating-gui-elements-in-multithreaded-pyqt)

Answer (score 2):

It is a pure fluke that your example works at all.

When you attempt to call `QtCore.QApplication.processEvents()`, a `NameError` will be raised, because the `QApplication` class is actually in the `QtGui` module, not the `QtCore` module. However, raising the exception has the side-effect of preventing your `scanner` object from being garbage-collected, and so the thread appears to run normally.

The correct way to fix your code is to keep a reference to the `scanner` object, and get rid of the `processEvents` line, which is not needed:

```
def scan(self):
    self.th = QtCore.QThread()
    # keep a reference to the scanner
    self.scanner = Scanner(r"D:\\")
    self.scanner.moveToThread(self.th)

    self.scanner.folderFound.connect(self.addFolder)
    self.scanner.done.connect(self.scanner.deleteLater)
    self.scanner.done.connect(self.quit)

    self.th.started.connect(self.scanner.scan)
    self.th.start()
```

The rest of your code is okay, and the example will now work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Event loop is not something that runs behind your back. You're *always* the one who has to run it. A thread cannot be doing two things at once: if your code is the locus of control, then *obviously* the event loop isn't! You need to return from your code to the event loop, and make sure that your code was called from the event loop. Any sort of a UI signal, networking event, or timeout is invoked from the event loop, so most likely your code already has the event loop on the call stack. To keep the loop spinning, you have to return to it, though.

Never use `processEvents` - instead, invert the control, so that the event loop calls into your code, and then you perform a chunk of work, and finally return back to the event loop.

The idiom for "keep my code working from event loop" is a zero-duration timer. The callable that performs the work is attached to the timeout signal.