# How to prevent the GUI from freezing using QThread?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4, python-multithreading, qthread

I have a GUI which needs to perform work that takes some time and I want to show the progress of this work, similar to the following:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyProgress(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # start loop with signal
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('loop', self)
        self.connect(self.button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.loop)

        # test button
        self.test_button = QtGui.QPushButton('test')
        self.connect(self.test_button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.test)

        self.pbar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setMinimum(0)
        self.pbar.setMaximum(100)

        # layout
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.test_button)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        vbox.addWidget(self.pbar)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.show()

    def update(self):
        self.pbar.setValue(self.pbar.value() + 1)

    def loop(self):
        for step in range(100):
            self.update()
            print step
            time.sleep(1)

    def test(self):
        if self.test_button.text() == 'test':
            self.test_button.setText('ok')
        else:
            self.test_button.setText('test')

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
view = MyProgress()
view.loop()  # call loop directly to check whether view is displayed
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I execute the code the `loop` method is called and it prints out the values as well as updates the progress bar. However the `view` widget will be blocked during the execution of `loop` and although this is fine for my application it doesn't look nice with Ubuntu. So I decided to move the work to a separate thread like this:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)

    def loop(self):
        for step in range(10):
            print step
            time.sleep(1)

class MyProgress(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # test button
        self.test_button = QtGui.QPushButton('test')
        self.connect(self.test_button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.test)

        self.pbar = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setMinimum(0)
        self.pbar.setMaximum(100)

        # layout
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.test_button)
        vbox.addWidget(self.pbar)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.show()

    def test(self):
        if self.test_button.text() == 'test':
            self.test_button.setText('ok')
        else:
            self.test_button.setText('test')

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

view = MyProgress()
work = Worker()

thread = QtCore.QThread()
work.moveToThread(thread)
# app.connect(thread, QtCore.SIGNAL('started()'), work.loop)  # alternative
thread.start()
work.loop()  # not called if thread started() connected to loop

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run this version of the script the loop starts running (the steps are displayed in the terminal) but the `view` widget is not shown. This is the first thing I can't quite follow. Because the only difference from the previous version here is that the loop runs in a different object however the `view` widget is created before and therefore should be shown (as it was the case for the previous script).

However when I connected the signal `started()` from `thread` to the `loop` function of `worker` then `loop` is never executed although I start the thread (in this case I didn't call `loop` on `worker`). On the other hand `view` is shown which makes me think that it depends whether `app.exec_()` is called or not. However in the 1st version of the script where `loop` was called on `view` it showed the widget although it couldn't reach `app.exec_()`.

Does anyone know what happens here and can explain how to execute `loop` (in a separate thread) without freezing `view`?

EDIT: If I add a `thread.finished.connect(app.exit)` the application exits immediately without executing `loop`. I checked out the 2nd version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783194/background-thread-with-qthread-in-pyqt?rq=1) which is basically the same what I do. But in both cases it finishes the job immediately without executing the desired method and I can't really spot why.

Answer (score 0):

The example doesn't work because communication between the worker thread and the GUI thread is all one way.

Cross-thread commnunication is usually done with signals, because it is an easy way to ensure that everything is done asynchronously and in a thread-safe manner. Qt does this by wrapping the signals as events, which means that an event-loop must be running for everything to work properly.

To fix your example, use the thread's `started` signal to tell the worker to start working, and then periodically emit a custom signal from the worker to tell the GUI to update the progress bar:

```
class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def loop(self):
        for step in range(0, 10):
            print step
            time.sleep(1)
            self.valueChanged.emit((step + 1) * 10)
...

thread = QtCore.QThread()
work.moveToThread(thread)
thread.started.connect(work.loop)
work.valueChanged.connect(view.pbar.setValue)
thread.start()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I know the example was only one way but the problem was that the `started` signal didn't trigger `worker.loop` although I connected them. But that must've been a OS problem (I created the example on some RedHat derivative) cause when I tried it on my Ubuntu it worked fine. Thus I think the question is redundant.

Comment: @a_guest. No, your second example wouldn't work anyway - it must have the changes I suggested to work properly.

Comment: It works, you just have to comment `work.loop` and uncomment `connect(...)` what I already indicated in my code. I was just puzzled by the fact that the widget `view` is shown when you call `loop` on `view` (as in my first example) but it is not shown when you create `view` separately and then call `loop` on `work`.

Comment: @a_guest. It clearly does not work: the progress bar is not updated. Your question asked how to make a non-blocking version of the first example, and to explain the interaction between threads, signals and the event-loop, which my answer did. I don't understand why you are being so argumentative about this.

Comment: My purpose was not an updating progr. bar but a GUI that doesn't freeze. That's why I can came up with my second example where I did basically the same what you did in you answer (I didn't update the progress bar because it was not shown in the first place and **that** was what puzzled me). If only about how to move tasks to different threads this question is a duplicate and not very informative. However if you know some stuff about PyQt4's signals and slots maybe you can answer me this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829553/is-it-safe-to-disconnect-a-slot-before-it-was-called