# PyQt Thread not running

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt

I am trying to run a long running test suite as a background thread with PyQt.  On osx the thread never runs, but on windows the thread runs if I include a print statement after starting the thread.  The code looks like this:

```
def runModuleTests(self):
    self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)

    self.testThread = QtCore.QThread()
    tr = TestRunner(self.on_testResult, self.moduleArticleNumber, self.moduleSerialNumber, self.testBedArticleNumber)
    tr.moveToThread(self.testThread)
    tr.testFinished.connect(self.testThread.quit)
    self.testThread.started.connect(tr.runModuleTests)
    self.testThread.start()
    print "This print out is here to make threads work.  UGLY HACK!"
```

I have these questions:

- Is this print statement causing my GUI to yield on windows, so the other thread starts?
- How can I get the thread to start on both mac osx and windows?
- Does the GIL mean I cannot get a responsive UI using PyQt?
- Am I doing things the wrong way?

I have taken inspiration from the answer to this question:
[Background thread with QThread in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783194/background-thread-with-qthread-in-pyqt)

Comment: possible that the `TestRunner` runs out of scope? (so `tr = ...` should be `self.tr = ...`)

Comment: Well done @Zaiborg - you got it.  I had assumed that adding the object to the thread would keep it in the scope... Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @Zaiborg was what I was missing.  You need to keep a handle on the object even if you move it to the thread.