# How to make Qt(PyQt) codes runs in order?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, python-3.4

Hello every one. I am making a desktop GUI application using PyQt5 on Windows 7.

In my application, there is a heavy workload. It is making a hash code of all files in specified directories and downloads from ftp if the files hash code is not equal with ftps file. On my system this takes about 5-6 minutes.

In my thought...

1. show widget first. ( of course, the 'self.show()' is prior to code of compare hash. )
2. compare hash code and download the files.

Code works properly, but widget show after `2.` ends. And this is a problem.
I want to my application runs step 1 first then step 2. What should I do?

Any help is apreciated

**Code:**

```
class showUI(QWidget):
  # make menu, toolbar, buttons, etc..
  self.show()

class compareHashAndDownload:
  # compare hash and download the files.

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = showUI()
  mainProcess = compareHashAndDownload()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You must enter the event loop (app.exec()) to make the widget appear, and not block the event loop while doing the download and computation (do the download asynchronous/event-based or in another thread).

Comment: Thank you, 'Frank Osterfeld'. But I'm not an expert at PyQt. Do you have any example of block/nonblock event loop and how to enter and edit event loop?

Comment: why not just call the `compareHashAndDownload` after the `self.show()` from inside the `showUI`

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI: That’s equivalent to what he is doing now, I think?

Comment: @GIRISHRAMNANI: Sorry but your solution doesn't make difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to fix this is to run the `compareHashAndDownload` in a separate `QThread`. This would also allow the widget to be interacted with, even before the long running function has completed.  You could also re-run the function later and not hang up the GUI in that time.

Using threads is quite complex. For example, you will need to arrange the GUI actions so they operate correctly when called before, during, or after the execution of the `compareHashAndDownload` function.

There are some nice examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783194/background-thread-with-qthread-in-pyqt) which will help you if you decide to go down this route.

However, a cheap and cheerful alternative would be to show a splash screen 
while you perform the `compareHashAndDownload`.  Here's a simple example:

```
class showUI(QWidget):
  splash = QtGui.QSplashScreen(QtGui.QPixmap(splashFileName))
  splash.show()
  # make menu, toolbar, buttons, etc..
  mainProcess = compareHashAndDownload()
  self.show()
  splash.finish(self)

class compareHashAndDownload:
  # compare hash and download the files.

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = showUI()

  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank yo very much 'strubbly'. You showed me a right way and good workaround! thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

you can directly call `compareHashAndDownload` from the `showUI` widget itself.
But if your compare method takes too long then the ui will wait from it to complete and thats not a nice experience.So keep that in mind.

```
class showUI(QWidget):
  # make menu, toolbar, buttons, etc..
  mainProcess = compareHashAndDownload()
  self.show()

class compareHashAndDownload:
  # compare hash and download the files.

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = showUI()

  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this will work fine is the method doesnt take that long, if it does then use qt's own `QThread` to run the method on seperate thread (not the most elegant solution but will work fine) .

Comment: As I mentioned, My code has heavy workload(5, 6minutes). So your solution makes no difference. I need the way to completely show the ui first. Your code result same as I write....