# Can not emit signal from not threaded slot in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5

According this example : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783194/background-thread-with-qthread-in-pyqt/33453124#33453124) ,I want to implement a thread based small application within a GUI. I have two files `TestMain.py` and `TestManager.py` (Worker class), which are connected with each other over `sys.path.append('...')`. In `TestMain.py`, I load my GUI, create thread and signal/slot connections, which act on functions in `TestManager.py`. In `TestManager.py` I do some calculations and want to visualize them in a `QTextEditor` at the same time. To do this, I have written following code:

**TestMain.py**

```
sys.path.append('../app/source')
from TestManager import *

class TestMain(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(TestMain, self).__init__(parent)

        self.manager= TestManager()
        self.thread= QThread()
        self.manager.moveToThread(self.thread)

        self.manager.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.manager.first_slot)
        self.thread.start()

        self.manager.printFirstSignal.connect(self.print_onTextEdit)

        self.offlinePushButton.clicked.connect(self.offline_slot)

    def offline_slot(self):
        manager.do_some_calc(self)

    def print_onTextEdit(self, str):
        self.outputTextEdit.append(str)
```

**Manager.py**

```
sys.path.append('../app/source')
from TestMain import *

class TestManager(QObject): #QtCore.QThread
    finished= pyqtSignal()
    printFirstSignal= pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent= None):
        super(TestManager, self).__init__(parent)

    def first_slot(self):
        self.printFirstSignal.emit('TEST')
        self.finished.emit()

    def do_some_calc(self):
        do_someting()
        TestManager.first_slot("do_some_calc")
```

If I do `self.thread.started.connect(self.manager.first_slot)` in `TestMain` and emit the `pyqtSignal` in function `first_slot()` in `TestManager`, then I can update my GUI without any problem. But if I call a slot (e.g `do_some_calc()`) in `TestManager` and want to also update the GUI from there, than I get a segmentation fault. Even if I create a separate signal for this function, it does not work. Cause I call this function in `TestMain` `self.offlinePushButton.clicked.connect(self.offline_slot)`

My question is. How can I call any function in `TestManager` internally or from `MainTest` so that I can still update the GUI?

Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: Hi, could you provide a minimal and runnable app of what you are trying to do ?

Comment: You can only update the gui from the main thread. If `TestManager` needs to trigger a gui update, you will need to send a signal back to `TestMain` and have it handle the update.

Comment: Actually I did it exactly. I have defined a signal in `TestManager` as ` testSignal= pyqtSignal(str)` and emitted in `def do_some_calc(self):` function like `self.testSignal.emit('Some str')`. In `TestMain` connected the signal like `self.manager.testSignal.connect(self.print_onTextEdit2)`. and defined function: `def print_onTextEdit2(self, value):    self.outputTE.append(value)`. The app crashes exactly, where I emit the signal in `TestManager`

Comment: Then I would guess there is some small mistake in your code. If you have an unhandled exception inside a PyQt slot it will crash your program, rather than print a traceback like you would expect. I suggest you wrap your slot code inside `try/except` blocks and print any captured errors to pinpoint the problem

Comment: @nasil122002. One way or another, you **must** use signals to communicate between threads.

Comment: Ok from expectation: ` try: self.testSignal.emit('Some str') except:  e = sys.exc_info() print('Exception :', e)` I get: `Exception : (<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError("'TestMain' object has no attribute 'testSignal'",), <traceback object at 0x0A583DA0>)` What it means? The signal is defined where it is called also in `TestManager` class. Why should have it somewhere else?