# Running multiple background threads using QThread in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

Having an issue calling multiple threads. I have no luck. Runs the first definition (procCounter) fine but does not display or run the second (procCounter2)

**Below is my main and my worker:**

```
    # main.py
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QGridLayout
    import sys
    import worker
    
    
    class Form(QWidget):
    
        def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
           self.label = QLabel("0")
           self.label2 = QLabel("1")
    
           # 1 - create Worker and Thread inside the Form
           self.obj = worker.Worker()  # no parent!
           self.thread = QThread()  # no parent!
    
           # 2 - Connect Worker`s Signals to Form method slots to post data.
           self.obj.intReady.connect(self.onIntReady)
           self.obj.intReady.connect(self.onIntReady2)
    
           # 3 - Move the Worker object to the Thread object
           self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)
    
           # 4 - Connect Worker Signals to the Thread slots
           self.obj.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
    
           # 5 - Connect Thread started signal to Worker operational slot method
           self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.procCounter)
           self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.procCounter2)
    
           # * - Thread finished signal will close the app if you want!
           #self.thread.finished.connect(app.exit)
    
           # 6 - Start the thread
           self.thread.start()
    
           # 7 - Start the form
           self.initUI()
    
    
        def initUI(self):
            grid = QGridLayout()
            self.setLayout(grid)
            grid.addWidget(self.label,0,0)
            grid.addWidget(self.label2,0,1)
            self.move(300, 150)
            self.setWindowTitle('thread test')
            self.show()
    
        def onIntReady(self, i):
            self.label.setText("{}".format(i))
            print(i)
    
        def onIntReady2(self, i):
            #self.label2.setText("{}".format(i))
            print(i)
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    form = Form()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Here is my worker:**

```
    # worker.py
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
    import time
    
    
    class Worker(QObject):
        finished = pyqtSignal()
        intReady = pyqtSignal(int)
    
    
            @pyqtSlot()
            def procCounter(self): # A slot takes no params
              for i in range(1, 100):
                time.sleep(.5)
                self.intReady.emit(i)
    
              self.finished.emit()
    
            @pyqtSlot(int)
            def procCounter2(self): # A slot takes no params
               for i in range(1000):
                   time.sleep(.2)
                 self.intReady.emit(i)
    
            self.finished.emit()
```

I have even tried adding n additional pyqtSignal such as: "intReady2 = pyqtSignal(int)" in the worker and then in the main adding " self.obj.intReady2.connect(self.onIntReady2)" But still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"obj" lives in the same thread so when invoking the slots they will execute the same thread so the first function it executes will block the other. The solution is to create 2 workers that live in different threads

```py
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    intReady = pyqtSignal(int)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def procCounter(self):
        pass


class Worker1(Worker):
    @pyqtSlot()
    def procCounter(self):
        for i in range(1, 100):
            time.sleep(.5)
            self.intReady.emit(i)
        self.finished.emit()


class Worker2(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def procCounter(self):
        for i in range(1000):
            time.sleep(.2)
            self.intReady.emit(i)
        self.finished.emit()
```

```py
self.obj1 = worker.Worker1()
self.thread1 = QThread()
self.obj1.moveToThread(self.thread1)
self.obj1.intReady.connect(self.onIntReady)
self.thread1.started.connect(self.obj.procCounter)

self.obj2 = worker.Worker2()
self.thread2 = QThread()
self.obj2.moveToThread(self.thread2)
self.obj2.intReady.connect(self.onIntReady2)
self.thread2.started.connect(self.obj2.procCounter)

self.thread1.start()
self.thread2.start()
```

Comment: possible to run multiple return emits in 1 definition? like if I wanted def procCounter(self) to emit 2 items/counts??? @eyllanesc

Answer (score -1):

The problem is `self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.procCounter)`, you need to replace it with `self.thread.started.connect(lambda: self.obj.procCounter())`
More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894098/sending-signals-to-thread-function-in-pyqt5-leads-to-typeerror-of-decorated-slot)

Comment: What you indicate will cause procCounter to run on the main thread causing the GUI to freeze