# Threading script doesn't terminate

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm a PyQt5 newbie. I've written the following code which should ideally terminate.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, pyqtSignal, QObject
import sys
import thread

class MainWindow(QObject):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.myMethod()        

    def myMethod(self):
        self.myThread = thread.MainWindow(self)
        self.myThread.threadTerminate.connect(self.finished)
        self.myThread.start()

    def finished(self, arg1):
        print("Message recieved is "+arg1)
        QCoreApplication.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    qApp = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    qApp.exec_()
```

The thread code is:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QCoreApplication, pyqtSignal
import sys
import time

class MainWindow(QThread):
    threadTerminate = pyqtSignal(bool)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.itsOver = False

    def run(self):
        print("Hello World!")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("Alice")
        time.sleep(4)
        print("Bob")
        time.sleep(4)
        self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        print("About to terminate....")
        self.itsOver = True
        self.threadTerminate.emit(self.itsOver)
        self.terminate()
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to trace the execution flow of my program and know the state of my variables?

Comment: There is a useful example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33453124/4265407

Comment: two things: 1 - `thread` is a low level library so use `threading` instead. 2 - `thread.MainWindow(self)` does this line even work? the `thread` module should not have a member named `MainWindow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a simple race condition.

When I add a `time.sleep(1)` between the call to `self.threadTerminate.emit` and `self.terminate`, the program finishes as expected (except for your print statement where str and bool cant be concatenated, naturally).

Without knowing the exact details of how Qt processes the signal/slot flow, I'd say that your call to `terminate` clears up the thread and its signals before the invocation of the connected slot in the `MainWindow`'s thread, thereby erasing the `finished` event from the event loop and skipping your call to `Quit()`.

In short: Do a `self.exit()` in the QThread instead. It's the graceful shutdown alternative to `terminate`, which as far as I've seen you should avoid whenever possible.

---

As a side note, maybe rethink your module and class namings. The `thread` module was a module in Python2, renamed to `_thread` in Python3. That confused me at first (same as the commenters above) since you have an own module called "thread.py". Furthermore, `MainWindow` resembles the name of `PyQt5.QtWidgets.QMainWindow`, while a `QCoreApplication` doesn't have "windows".