# PyQt5: How to properly use QtProgressBar using QThread while a function is running

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qthread

I'm completely new to PyQt5 and I'm having trouble to connect a function to a QtProgressBar.

I'm using the script shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59977505/10603181) to create the popup, thread, etc. There, they connect the progress bar with the Worker Class. How can I connect my function 'testFunction' to make the progress bar run while this function is running?

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, QObject, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QProgressBar, QVBoxLayout


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Widget")
        self.h_box = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.main_window_button = QPushButton("Start")
        self.popup = PopUpProgressB()  # Creating an instance instead as an attribute instead of creating one
        # everytime the button is pressed
        self.main_window_button.clicked.connect(self.popup.start_progress)  # To (re)start the progress
        self.h_box.addWidget(self.main_window_button)
        self.setLayout(self.h_box)
        self.show()


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    intReady = pyqtSignal(int)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def proc_counter(self):  # A slot takes no params
        for i in range(1, 100):
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.intReady.emit(i)
        self.finished.emit()

    def testFunction(self, rvg, mes):
        df = pd.read_excel(self.rvg, sheet_name=self.mes,
                           skiprows=2, decimal=',')
        df = df.dropna(how='all')
        df_obj = df.select_dtypes(['object'])
        df[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
        df['RFO'] = df['RFO'].str.strip().replace('  ', ' ')
        df = df.T
        df = df.groupby(level=0).sum()
        df.columns = df.loc['NOME']
        df = df.drop(index='NOME')
        df.to_excel('testFunction.xlsx', encoding='utf-8',
                    sheet_name='testFunction')
        return df

class PopUpProgressB(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 500, 75)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pbar)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 550, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress Bar')
        self.obj = Worker()
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.obj.intReady.connect(self.on_count_changed)
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.hide)  # To hide the progress bar after the progress is completed
        self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.proc_counter)

    def start_progress(self):  # To restart the progress every time
        self.show()
        self.thread.start()

    def on_count_changed(self, value):
        self.pbar.setValue(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Where in your code do you instantiate RateioDRE?

Comment: Well, I didn't instantiate because I have no clue about how to connect to the progress bar with that.I tried to include dRateio to Worker Class but, again, I got stuck. It seems I'm too far away from my objective. Any tip about how to start? Anyway, I have edited the post and removed RateioDRE, then created a testFunction inside Worker Class. Sorry about my lack of knowledge =/