# Is there a way to cancel a background worker task in PyQt5 using a pushButton?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to make the background worker start with the start button and stop with the stop button. When I push start the program starts but I can't stop it and it also exits the gui when completed. Sorry, I am a novice just trying to learn. I found this example here and I am just trying to expand on it.
[Background thread with QThread in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783194/background-thread-with-qthread-in-pyqt)

```
# main.py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton
import sys
import worker

class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label = QLabel("0") # start out at 0.

        ##### I added the stuff below 6/8/2020 ####################################
        k = 2
        self.button1 = QPushButton("Push to start") # create start button
        self.button2 = QPushButton("Push to Stop") # create a stop button.
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.start) # connect button to function
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.stop) # connect button to function
        ########################################################################

        # 1 - create Worker and Thread inside the Form
        self.obj = worker.Worker()  # no parent! #### Calls to worker.py
        self.thread = QThread()  # no parent! #### Creates an empty thread

        # 2 - Connect Worker`s Signals to Form method slots to post data.
        self.obj.intReady.connect(self.onIntReady)  # connects the definition below

        # 3 - Move the Worker object to the Thread object
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)

        # 4 - Connect Worker Signals to the Thread slots
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)

        # 5 - Connect Thread started signal to Worker operational slot method
        #self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.procCounter(k)) #### starts the counter in worker.py

        # 6 - Start the thread
        self.thread.start()

        # 7 - Start the form
        self.initUI()


    def start(self):
        k=2
        self.obj.procCounter(k)
    def stop(self):
        self.thread.quit()

    def initUI(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)
        grid.addWidget(self.label,0,1)
        grid.addWidget(self.button1, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.button2, 0, 2)
        self.move(300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('thread test')
        self.show()

    def onIntReady(self, i):
        self.label.setText("{}".format(i))
        print(i)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
# worker.py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
import time


class Worker(QObject): # this is called by Worker.worker() in main.py
    finished = pyqtSignal() # sets up to emit a signal back to main.py
    intReady = pyqtSignal(int) # emits an integer to main.py def onIntReady

    @pyqtSlot()
    def procCounter(self,k): # A slot takes no params
        for i in range(1, 10):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.intReady.emit(i*k) # emits the signal to onIntReady
    #def procCounter(self): # A slot takes no params
    #    for i in range(1, 100):
    #        time.sleep(1)
    #        self.intReady.emit(i)
        self.finished.emit()
```

Comment: Typo: use `self.thread.quit()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You were right on that part. But when i push start the UI freezes and won't let me push stop.

Comment: I did not say that it is the solution, if the cause of the error was a TYPO then I would have voted to close it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that.