# my code window doesnt responding when its calculating stuffs

Tags: python, loops, pyqt5, window

im pretty new in python. I wrote a code that analyzes picture's pixels. I also make a window with Qt Designer. but when I run the program my Qt window stops responding. you know, app deosnt responding error.

I mean code is working I can see the outputs in console and if I wait enough program finishes the analyzing and window starts to respond again. I know analyzing a lot of stuff is hard but how can I edit my code to not mess up my Qt window? is it possible tho?

basically my code is two big "for i in range" command

Comment: You shouldn't do blocking operations in your UI thread but use a [background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783194/background-thread-with-qthread-in-pyqt) instead.

Comment: hmm didnt know there is a thing like that exist. makes sense actually. I will work on that. thanks