# How do I make web requests in a PyQt5 application without hanging the UI?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 application running in Python 3.7 that makes a lot of web request, but no more than one or two at a time.  Most requests are quick, but sometimes take several seconds.  The whole UI hangs until the requests complete.  I have a full sample application below to demonstrate this.

Looking around, [some people](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/) recommend [using `QThread`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33453124/57752) but if I try to do that, I get complaints about accessing UI objects from the wrong thread.  That method also prevents me from returning the web response to the caller.  In the sample code below, the response is only used to print the status code, but in the actual application the JSON responses are parsed and used.  Most answers to this question I find are more than five years old, often referencing PyQt4 or older, or referencing packages that are now obsolete such as [grequests](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests) or [request-threads](https://github.com/requests/requests-threads).  Some people reference [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/) (still in beta) or [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/), which has its own event loop and doesn't always play nice inside PyQt5 applications.

The sample is as stripped down as possible to demonstrate the problem.  if you click "Make Request" and immediately click on "Click Counter" you'll see that the counter doesn't increase until the web request has completed.  This is not surprising given that the request is blocking the Qt event loop.

How can I just simply get the current code to work where the requests are submitted and managed asynchronously, but still being able to pass a response back to the caller?

Here is `test.py`:

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime

import requests
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from requests import RequestException


class UI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('test.ui', self)
        self.web = WebManager(self)
        self.issue_request_button.clicked.connect(self.issue_request)
        self.issue_click_button.clicked.connect(self.click_counter)
        self.show()

    def click_counter(self):
        self.click_count_label.setText(str(int(self.click_count_label.text()) + 1))

    def issue_request(self):
        r = self.web.issue_get(self.request_url.text())
        print(r.status_code if r is not None else 'No successful response')


class WebManager:
    def __init__(self, gui):
        self.gui = gui

    def issue_get(self, url_request):
        try:
            start = datetime.now()
            headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            r = requests.get(url_request, headers=headers)
            self.fill_request_response_info(r, datetime.now() - start)
            return r
        except RequestException as e:
            print(f'Request failed with an Exception of type {type(e).__name__}')
            return None

    def fill_request_response_info(self, response, total_request_time):
        request = response.request
        self.gui.request_url_textbox.setText(request.method + ' ' + request.url)
        self.gui.request_headers_textbox.setText('\n'.join(k + ':' + v for k, v in request.headers.items()))
        self.gui.response_status_textbox.setText(f'{response.status_code}  {response.reason}')
        self.gui.response_elapsed_time_textbox.setText(f'{response.elapsed} / {total_request_time}')
        self.gui.response_headers_textbox.setText('\n'.join(k + ':' + v for k, v in response.headers.items()))
        self.gui.response_body_textbox.setText(response.content.decode('utf-8'))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = UI()
app.exec()
```

and here is the UI file that it needs `test.ui`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>750</width>
    <height>734</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Test Window</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="issue_request_button">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Make Request</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="text">
         <string>URL:</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLineEdit" name="request_url">
        <property name="text">
         <string>https://archive.org/advancedsearch.php?q=subject:google+sheets&amp;output=json</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="issue_click_button">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Click Counter</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="click_count_label">
        <property name="text">
         <string>0</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QGroupBox" name="http_request_groupBox">
      <property name="title">
       <string>HTTP Request</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="req_url_label">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Request URL:</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
         <item>
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="request_url_textbox"/>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="req_headers_label">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Request Headers:</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QTextEdit" name="request_headers_textbox"/>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QGroupBox" name="http_response_groupBox">
      <property name="title">
       <string>HTTP Response</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2" stretch="0,0,1,0,1">
       <item>
        <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout" rowstretch="0,0">
         <item row="0" column="0">
          <widget class="QLabel" name="http_status_label">
           <property name="text">
            <string>HTTP Status:</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="0" column="3">
          <widget class="QLabel" name="elapsed_time_label">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Elapsed Time:</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="1" column="0">
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="response_status_textbox"/>
         </item>
         <item row="1" column="3">
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="response_elapsed_time_textbox"/>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="response_headers_label">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Response Headers:</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QTextEdit" name="response_headers_textbox"/>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="response_body_label">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Response Body:</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QTextEdit" name="response_body_textbox"/>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <tabstops>
  <tabstop>issue_request_button</tabstop>
  <tabstop>request_url</tabstop>
  <tabstop>issue_click_button</tabstop>
  <tabstop>request_url_textbox</tabstop>
  <tabstop>request_headers_textbox</tabstop>
  <tabstop>response_status_textbox</tabstop>
  <tabstop>response_elapsed_time_textbox</tabstop>
  <tabstop>response_headers_textbox</tabstop>
  <tabstop>response_body_textbox</tabstop>
 </tabstops>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: 1. If you use threading, you must **not** directly access UI elements from the external thread; using QThread is the right choice, but it requires that you create custom signals, and then emit the resulting values with those signals, then connect them to the methods of the UI class that actually change it. 2. Instead of using requests, consider [QNetworkAccessManager](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html), which is asynchronous and provides a full thread-safe API.

Comment: Sigh.  The referenced answers at the top do not help me at all.  I know what the problem is but not what the solution is.  StackOverflow isn't as helpful as it used to be.  I have unsuccessfully tried everything referenced in the two answers.

Comment: You're experienced enough to know that complaining won't help you a lot here. I've seen those questions, and they both provide suitable solutions for your issue. If you believe that they don't solve your problem, you should already know what to do: add more information to your post, possibly updating with the attempts based on those answers, and/or explaining *why* those posts don't help you.

Comment: I agree, my comment was venting.  I had previously seen answers very much like those in my search for information.  Qt and threading is quirky and picky enough that absent a fully working solution against a recent version of Qt, old answers or references to QNetworkAccessManager are not a lot of help.  I've spent hours trying to get QNAM code working.  It's extremely finicky.  It's nowhere close to as easy as the requests library is to use..  When I use a QThread, either it still blocks the event loop or it complains I'm accessing controls from the wrong thread.  This isn't easy to get working

Comment: Qt has a steep (and continuous) learning curve. After years of using it, I still find myself surprised to find something I didn't know about, even for very standard classes. It's extremely complex, but it's also very complete as much as it's sometimes hard to get it. Nonetheless, as soon as you got the hang of it and understand its way, it all makes sense. The QtNetwork classes are actually "simple", as soon as you understand them, so I strongly suggest you to make up a basic example that sums your attempts, and provide it to us so that we'll be able to help you with it.