# Socket server in PyQt5 freeze and crash

Tags: python, sockets, pyqt5

I have a simple PyQt window with a socket setup to listen on a port, and I also have a client that wants to send data to this server.

```
import time
import socket
from PyQT5.QTCore import QTimer

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        ... UI stuff
        
        self.initSocket()
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateData)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def initSocket(self):
        binded = False
        while True:
            self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            if not binded:
                try:
                    self.socket.bind(('localhost', 12345))
                    self.socket.listen(5)
                    binded = True
                    print("server binded")
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error binding: {e}")
                    time.sleep(1)
 
    def updateData(self):
        print("starting update data")
        try:
            conn, addr = self.socket.accept()
            print("accepted connection from client")
            data = self.socket.recv(1024).decode()
            data_dict = json.loads(data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error updating data: {e}")
```

So far the UI is functional on its own. However after setting up sockets, the program would display the UI, print the "server binded", then the "starting update data", then the whole process would freeze and crash.
Side note in case it matters, everything is all setup on a raspberry pi4, including the client program that the server is listening to.

Comment: adding the necessary imports will help...

Comment: Updated imports used in this code block

Comment: 1. When using sockets, note that without setting a timeout to the current socket (specially tcp), calling recv or send will block the current thread until the function finishes executing. As PyQt5 uses an event system, a blocking function will prevent pyqt5 from processing incoming events, thus freezing the application; 2. Using time.sleep is incompatible with PyQt5. Try using QObject.thread().msleep() instead, given you're using a QObject; 3. Do not try to use the python threading module. Use the PyQt5 QThread class instead, and use signals to when trying to execute a QWidget method.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have figured out my own solution, PyQTimer just crashes the program for some reason. To achieve the same effect, I ended up using a while loop **inside** updateData() and putting it on a new thread so it can loop in the background while the UI can work its own thing, instead of calling it again and again using QTimer as the interval. I also cleaned up the initSocket() and UpdateData() a little bit.

```
import time
import socket
import threading

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        ... UI stuff
        
        self.initSocket()
        updateData_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.updateData)
        updateData_thread.start()

   def initSocket(self):
        host = 'localhost'
        port = 12345

        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((host, port))
        self.socket.listen(2)
        print(f"Listening on {host}:{port}")
        
 
    def updateData(self):
        while True:
            try:
                conn, addr = self.socket.accept()
                print(f"Connected to {addr}")
                data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
                data_dict = json.loads(data)
                ime.sleep(0.4)
                
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Error: {str(e)}')
                conn.close()
                time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I understand you've solved your problem. However, I urge you to check my comment above to stop it right away common problems that will probably give you headaches when using Qt5 with python.

Comment: @RyanXu Please consider all the above suggestions with ***extreme*** awareness. The code you're providing is leaving out what are probably very important aspects of your implementation, so we have no real way to tell it for sure, but, considering your approach (both from this answer and from your original question), it seems clear that you're trying to access data from multiple threads in a way that is ***NOT*** safe. Most importantly, UI elements are not thread-safe and, generally speaking, any attempt to access thread-unsafe objects from any thread has to be considered dangerous.

Comment: I'm not an expert when it comes to threading. From my understanding, I should call my function that accesses the data to update the UI using a lock?

`with self.lock: self.updateUI(data_dict)`

then in updateUI:

`with self.lock: #change some UI with the data`

Comment: Just search any article such as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6789205/14956120) on the internet that briefly explains how to use QThreads in python. There's plenty of them on the internet. I prefer to use the QObject.moveToThread() approach, but you can also subclass QThread if you know what you're doing. In order to exchange data "QThread -> QWidget" use a pyqtSignal. To exchange data "Main Thread -> QThread", you may use any conventional means you wish. Using QMutexes works just fine (it's how I do it). But use a Qt5 compliant way. Do not rely on native python modules.

Comment: Thank you Carl, I never looked far into how PyQt operated and just assumed it will work fine with native modules. I will see what I can do about my specific use case in a Qt5 compliant way.