# PyQt5 application not responding during operation if any event is noticed by the app

Tags: pyqt5, qthread

I have created a simple application to replicate this issue.
Basically, if you click away or click on the app (replicating an event that is handled by the application), then it sets it into the queue and stops updating. This also prompts a "Not Responding" notification. For whatever reason with the code I have just typed up, it will not witness this issue until the 6th iteration.

I have done some research on threading, but nothing seems to help. Maybe I am missing something.

Here is how the code works. All you need to do is click on the run button. This should prompt the application to update all 5 edit boxes on the right with a new incremented number value every 1 second. And the app will also alert the user in the text field on the right.

My main curiosity is this: is there a way to create a thread that queues all events such that they do not affect the app from updating the user on what is going on internally? Or is there a way to disable all events all together to make sure that the only thing that happens during operation is updating the user on events within the app.

Here is the code:

## QApp.py

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QLineEdit


class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Increment App')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 300)

        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # Layouts
        main_layout = QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        input_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        output_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        text_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        main_layout.addLayout(input_layout)
        main_layout.addLayout(output_layout)
        main_layout.addLayout(text_layout)

        # Input Edit Fields
        self.input_fields = []
        for i in range(5):
            input_field = QLineEdit(self)
            input_field.setText("0")
            input_layout.addWidget(input_field)
            self.input_fields.append(input_field)

        # Output Edit Fields
        self.output_fields = []
        for i in range(5):
            output_field = QLineEdit(self)
            output_field.setReadOnly(True)
            output_layout.addWidget(output_field)
            self.output_fields.append(output_field)

        # Text Box
        self.text_box = QTextEdit(self)
        text_layout.addWidget(self.text_box)

        # Run Button
        self.run_button = QPushButton('Run', self)
        self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.run_button_clicked)
        text_layout.addWidget(self.run_button)

    def run_button_clicked(self):
        try:
            # Get the current values from input fields
            input_values = [int(input_field.text()) for input_field in self.input_fields]

            while input_values[0] < 101:
                # Increment each value and update the output fields
                for i in range(5):
                    input_values[i] += 1
                    self.output_fields[i].setText(str(input_values[i]))

                # Update the text box
                self.text_box.append("Updated values in output fields.")

                self.run_button.setEnabled(False)

                self.repaint()
                time.sleep(1)

            self.text_box.append("All values have reached 100.")

        except ValueError:
            self.text_box.append("Invalid input. Please enter valid integers.")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

See the attached image for an idea of what it will look like after an event is witnessed by the app.

[image]

I have tried using what is recommended in this question: [Background thread with QThread in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783194/background-thread-with-qthread-in-pyqt)

But I still have no luck even when using threading.

Comment: Ui events must remain and be handled in the main thread, which should *never* be blocked by functions like `time.sleep()`. Yet, it's unclear what would be the actual purpose (or requirement) of having the user input values every second. Can you please clarify that part and explain the real case scenario for which you're trying to do that?

Comment: Sure! @musicamante This was just an example. The actual code is much more complicated. But I am using a python script to interact with Electrical Power Supplies and Power Analyzers using `pyvisa` and `SCPI` commands. For that reason, I am using `time.sleep()` in various locations to allow the communication between the device and my application to complete its full handshake.

What would your recommendation be instead?

Comment: Then you need to make your question more clear. For instance, how are those input fields updated? Does the user enter the values or are you just "simulating" input from those libraries? Or does the user need to "react" to events coming from the libraries, which may happen depending on different aspects? Note that such systems normally use threading to communicate with sensors and similar devices, so you need to put all the related communication to a separate QThread and communicate with the ui using signals (widgets are **not** thread safe and must *never* be accessed by external threads).

Comment: Remember that while examples should be kept as simple as possible, they should also actually reflect the actual scenario in which the program finally works. Right now your code doesn't seem to do anything related to what you mentioned in your comment, so please take your time to clarify the actual situation in which the program will function and how user interaction should eventually happen.

Comment: It may be possible you just simply misunderstood my point? I do believe everything I have posted is well representative of the question. Maybe threading is simply not the answer? But in the actual interface, the user inputs a set of general values for the algorithm that is created upon clicking the run button. In which case, during operation (in which can take hours), the algorithm will query the devices and ask for their current values. And those values will then be populated in the output edit fields. During operation I do not expect for the user to do anything but watch.

Comment: But in the instance in which they click away from the application during operation, the application will begin to not respond, and thus, not update anymore. Which is an issue in regard to being able to watch the progress.

So in that case, all I need to know is how do I make sure that the app is always updating those values and never goes into a "Not Responding" situation. Which in my opinion, is well documented in the question.

Comment: According to your explanation, then no, the example does *not* represent your case: user events are *completely* different from events coming from other sources, especially in case of libraries that may poll external devices. The event loop *must* be kept running, and that's exactly why you cannot have any block (while loops, `sleep()`, etc) in the main thread. I'm not familiar with the libraries you mentioned, but if you need a loop to communicate with those devices, that **must** happen in a separate thread, and then you can only interface with the UI using signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, there are many examples of answers on SO that dwell with QThreads, and explain their usage. [This is one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6789205/14956120) I hold it close since I started learning / using them. It basically tells you how to create a custom thread/worker, and make code run on another thread.

Now, about what musicamante had said on all of these comments: he's indeed correct:

- You shouldn't call QWidget's methods in another thread;
- You shouldn't use time.sleep;

These are straight forward guidelines of how to use threading in Qt5 + Python. I'll try to explain them to you if you're interested. If not, just skip to the bottom there's a script example in there.

**So, why you shouldn't call QWidget's methods in another thread?**

I'm no expert, but I am using QThreads for a while. Try to imagine the following scenario: on the main thread, once you call QApplication.exec(), Qt5 starts an Event Loop. Think of it as a while (True) loop that executes as long as the user doesn't click in the X button of the window.

Inside this infinite loop, widgets are being constantly updated and redrawn over time. So, their methods are being called over and over without the user's knowledge.

If you create a QThread, and call a QWidget method inside that thread, there's going to be a chance that there will be a conflict: the same instance of a QWidget will execute method A in the main thread, and that instance will execute method B in the QThread at the same time. Once it happens, it can cause a series of reading/writting operations on the same variable (memory, files, pointers of data, ...), at the same time.

This is bad.

In order to fix that, we could use a QMutex. However, we cannot edit the Qt5's source code, and we don't even want to. It would be easy to mess things up. As we can't do that, QWidget's methods are not thread-safe. So it's unwise to call them in another thread.

**How can we do that, then?**

We use signals.

Qt5 runs an event loop. Think of it as queue (First in, First out). You schedule an event, and at some point, that event is readen, and processed. Once you emit a signal, that signal is catched by the Qt5 event loop, and eventually it is processed, executing every connected listener.

So, in order to execute a method from a QWidget inside the QThread, you don't call the method directly:

1. We create a custom signal within the QThread (as a static variable);
2. We connect the QWidget method to the signal (on the main thread);
3. We emit the signal from the QThread, passing any arguments from the signal -> listener.

What happens in the background once you emit a signal, is that it doesn't execute the method right away. It sends a notification to the main thread's event loop, and when the notification is readen, it is processed and then the respective listener (QWidget's method) is called.

So there's always a delay of a few frames.

However, even if there's a delay of emitting signals and executing listeners, you can always rest assured that listeners will be executed when a respective signal is emitted. So it's a reliable way of exchanging data.

**Why time.sleep is bad?**

As I've written above, Qt5 runs an infinite event loop once QApplication.exec() is called. If you call time.sleep(), it will freeze the current thread, the main thread for a while.

This will cause the event loop to halt immediately for X seconds. What can be seen by the user, is that the application freezes and becomes unresponsive. The cursor's icon changes into an hourglass/blue spinner or something (like in windows), and the application gives itself away to be stuck at some heavy processing.

So, in terms of using GUIs, this is bad for the user experience. And the user will probably start clicking erratically and the application will be forced to shutdown. It happens to all of us.

**Now, I'll provide you an example of what you should do IMHO:**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QLineEdit
import copy
import sys

# Our worker is agnostic of the GUI. It's simply used to process some
# data and once it's done or has some output available, it can send it
# back to the main thread using signals.
class Worker(QObject):

    # Parameter is a tuple: (index: int, text: str)
    updateOutput = pyqtSignal(object)

    # Parameter is a string.
    appendTextBox = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_values = []

    # On this example, we're fetching data on the main thread, and keep
    # the list's reference on the on the thread side. 
    #
    # So, while we're calling this function on the main thread, we know
    # for sure that the thread hadn't started yet.
    #
    # If you plan to use data that is referenced both on the main thread,
    # AND the QThread side, guard the variable getter/setter with QMutexes.
    def setInputValues(self, ivs):
        self.input_values = ivs

    # Everything in this scope executes in another thread.
    def run(self):
        try:
            while (self.input_values[0] < 101):
                # Increment each value and update the output fields
                for i in range(len(self.input_values)):
                    self.input_values[i] += 1

                    # Don't ever call QWidgets methods in another thread.
                    #
                    # Use a signal to schedule that method to be executed
                    # on the main thread instead.
                    #
                    # Pass whichever parameter you want to that function.
                    self.updateOutput.emit((i, str(self.input_values[i])))

                # Simulate some heavy processing or simply force a way
                # to visualize the animation.
                #
                # Note: for some reason, in my case at least (PySide2 Win11), I
                # must call self.thread() instead of using self directly to call
                # QThread.msleep.
                self.thread().msleep(1000)
            
            # Again, emit signals instead of calling QWidgets methods on the other thread.
            self.appendTextBox("Updated values in output fields.")

        except ValueError:

            # Again, emit signals instead of calling QWidgets methods on the other thread.
            self.appendTextBox.emit("Invalid input. Please enter valid integers.")

# I've skipped the QMainWindow on purpose to diminish code.
class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    # Runs on main thread
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Increment App')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 300)

        # Layouts
        main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        input_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        output_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        text_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        main_layout.addLayout(input_layout)
        main_layout.addLayout(output_layout)
        main_layout.addLayout(text_layout)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

        # Input Edit Fields
        self.input_fields = []
        for i in range(5):
            input_field = QLineEdit(self)
            input_field.setText("0")
            input_layout.addWidget(input_field)
            self.input_fields.append(input_field)

        # Output Edit Fields
        self.output_fields = []
        for i in range(5):
            output_field = QLineEdit(self)
            output_field.setReadOnly(True)
            output_layout.addWidget(output_field)
            self.output_fields.append(output_field)

        # Text Box
        self.text_box = QTextEdit(self)
        text_layout.addWidget(self.text_box)

        # Run Button
        self.run_button = QPushButton('Run', self)
        self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.run_button_clicked)
        text_layout.addWidget(self.run_button)

        # -------------------------------------------------
        # - Thread Initialization
        # -------------------------------------------------

        # 1. Instantiate a QObject Worker.
        # - This is a matter of taste, I prefer to use the moveToThread approach
        #   when dealing with QThreads.
        self.worker = Worker()

        # 2. Create the thread and use moveToThread.
        self.update_thread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.update_thread)
        
        # 3. pyqtSignal Logic:
        # - When Worker.updateOutput signal is emitted, it will execute
        # updateIndexedOutput on the main thread with the respective parameters:
        #     - its a tuple (index, text)
        self.worker.updateOutput.connect(self.updateIndexedOutput)

        # 4. pyqtSignal Logic:
        # - When Worker.appendTextBox signal is emitted, it will execute
        # QTextEdit.append method on the main thread with a string parameter
        # provided by the worker (executing on the other thread).
        self.worker.appendTextBox.connect(self.text_box.append)

        # 5. Set which functions will run on the other thread. 
        # In this case only this one:
        self.update_thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)

    # Runs on main thread
    def run_button_clicked(self):
        try:
            # Get the current values from input fields
            input_values = [int(input_field.text()) for input_field in self.input_fields]

            # Start the update thread
            self.worker.setInputValues(input_values)
            self.update_thread.start()

            # Disable the run button
            self.run_button.setEnabled(False)
        except:
            self.text_box.append("Invalid input. Please enter valid integers.")

    # Runs on main thread
    def updateIndexedOutput(self, data):
        try:
            # Extract values from tuple
            index, text = data
            self.output_fields[index].setText(text)
        except Exception as error:
            print(error)

####
app = QApplication()
win = MyApp()
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

---

In the script above, I use QThread.msleep to simulate heavy processing. You shouldn't really call this for anything else. A function that gets any thread stuck for no reason, is not useful at all, specially if you want to close the application (you'd have to wait for it to finish). In this example, however, we are not waiting the QThread to finish its process to clean things properly on shutdown.

If you're waiting for another process output, or a peripheral device to provide you with data, you can just set a while (True) loop and wait for the result. As you're using another thread, a while (True) loop will not freeze the main application anymore.

If the script doesn't work, just let me know. I use PySide2 on Win11 so there might be some typos in that case.

Comment: A few corrections, if I may. Widgets are not constantly updated, since widgets are buffered paint surfaces: they only get repainted if necessary, which is on first show (or after showing again), when the widget schedules a repaint with `update()` or calls `repaint()`, when it's resized, when any other overlapped widget is repainted (including children or parents in most cases). All Qt classes are to be considered non thread-safe (unless where specified), but the most important limit of widgets is access to drawing resources, which can only happen in the QApplication thread due to library »

Comment: » (and most importantly, system) "limitations"; that's also the reason for which we cannot normally create QPixmaps in external threads, since pixmaps use the underlying window system to manage pixel data and their representation. Note that `QThread.sleep()` (and related) is fundamentally identical to `time.sleep()`, since both tell the system to temporarily suspend the thread. Also, any blocking in the main thread does make the UI unresponsive, but events are still queued by the system: in fact, if a user event happens during a block that is short enough, it will be processed once control »

Comment: » returns to the event loop, and that's why it's also possible, and acceptable in certain situations, to have temporary blocks that periodically allow queued event handling (including input events) by using `processEvents()`. Finally, it's important to highlight the fact that any while loop in the thread *must* release control periodically: if the worker is doing I/O that's normally fine (since the OS itself does *wait* while reading/writing), but any other heavy computation may still block the main thread, because the external one doesn't return control until finished.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I found the answer to my question. If you would like to get rid of this issue, just use the following code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QPushButton, \
    QLineEdit


class UpdateThread(QThread):
    update_signal = pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self, input_values=None, output_fields=None, text_box=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_values = input_values
        self.output_fields = output_fields
        self.text_box = text_box

    def run(self):

        try:
            while self.input_values[0] < 101:
                # Increment each value and update the output fields
                for i in range(5):
                    self.input_values[i] += 1
                    self.output_fields[i].setText(str(self.input_values[i]))

                # Update the text box
                self.text_box.append("Updated values in output fields.")

                self.msleep(1000)  # Sleep for 1 second

            self.text_box.append("All values have reached 100.")

        except ValueError:
            self.text_box.append("Invalid input. Please enter valid integers.")


class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Increment App')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 300)

        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # Layouts
        main_layout = QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        input_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        output_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        text_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        main_layout.addLayout(input_layout)
        main_layout.addLayout(output_layout)
        main_layout.addLayout(text_layout)

        # Input Edit Fields
        self.input_fields = []
        for i in range(5):
            input_field = QLineEdit(self)
            input_field.setText("0")
            input_layout.addWidget(input_field)
            self.input_fields.append(input_field)

        # Output Edit Fields
        self.output_fields = []
        for i in range(5):
            output_field = QLineEdit(self)
            output_field.setReadOnly(True)
            output_layout.addWidget(output_field)
            self.output_fields.append(output_field)

        # Text Box
        self.text_box = QTextEdit(self)
        text_layout.addWidget(self.text_box)

        # Run Button
        self.run_button = QPushButton('Run', self)
        self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.run_button_clicked)
        text_layout.addWidget(self.run_button)

        # Initialize the thread for updates
        self.update_thread = UpdateThread(self.input_fields, self.output_fields, self.text_box)
        self.update_thread.update_signal.connect(self.update_thread.run)

    def run_button_clicked(self):
        try:
            # Get the current values from input fields
            input_values = [int(input_field.text()) for input_field in self.input_fields]

            # Start the update thread
            self.update_thread.input_values = input_values
            self.run_button.setEnabled(False)
            self.update_thread.start()

            # Disable the "Run" button
            self.run_button.setEnabled(True)

        except ValueError:
            self.text_box.append("Invalid input. Please enter valid integers.")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this case, by adding a Qthread class and then calling to it and running the code within it, you can move your application as well as update it with no issue. The fix is using self.msleep(1000) instead of time.sleep(1).

Comment: Using `msleep` or `time.sleep` is fundamentally the same, so that's not "the fix". The *real* fix was moving the blocking loop to a separate thread. Still, you're doing exactly what I explicitly told you to **NOT** do: accessing the UI from another thread. As already said, UI elements are **not** thread-safe, and trying to access them (especially to set properties) is wrong and may lead to unexpected behavior or even fatal crash. Your connection to the `run` function is also wrong: that function is internally called by the thread and should not be explicitly accessed. Besides, you're not even»

Comment: » emitting that signal, so that's pointless. Instead, signals should be used to emit values that will eventually be used in the GUI: you must create signals that will be connected to the function(s) of the main window that will eventually call the related widget functions (`setText()`, etc.) and then signals will be emitted from the thread. In fact, the thread should know absolutely *nothing* about the UI, it's only responsibility is to "work" the data (eg. by communicating with devices) and emit the result. I repeat: do not **ever** try to directly access the UI from external threads.

Comment: I definitely do not want to sound rude here. I don't really understand threading and am very novice with the thought of using threads with PyQt5. For that reason, I have polled the community to HELP me find a solution. Your concern is definitely useful. But your lack of answering my question is extremely frustrating because it gives me a false sense of hope. While I respect that I may be doing something wrong, I do not know what I do not know. I would very much appreciate an actual answer rather than just "You are not doing this correct." Thank you.

Comment: I've not given an answer because: 1. as said, your question didn't make it clear what actually should happen with the libraries you mentioned; 2. there are plenty of resources regarding QThread, including dozens of answers even here on StackOverflow (and we should avoid duplicates). I didn't just told you that it's not correct, I explained why and how to avoid it even before you attempted it: widgets are **not** thread-safe, and you *must* use signals (emitted from the thread) connected to functions that will actually access UI elements *in the main thread* (aka, within methods of `MyApp`).