Correct way of closing a thread in PySide
I am currently designing a Software using PySide6 which connects to 3 electronic components/instruments to obtain various scientific reading simultaneously.
I use the thread functionality of PySide6 to achieves the parallel working of each components.
I am using this template to design my threads (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33453124/5959601).
However, I am a bit confused as to how to close each thread. Currently, I use the following statements:
self.thread.deleteLater()
self.worker.deleteLater()

Is this is the correct way to do it ? (Note: the threads are getting stopped and I am not having any issues yet)

deleteLater deletes the Qt object (the thread handler and the worker instance), does not "close the thread". Please clarify what you actual mean with that "close".

QThread has a .terminate() method which will stop execution but it generally should be avoided.
from the docs:

Warning
This function is dangerous and its use is discouraged. The thread can
be terminated at any point in its code path. Threads can be terminated
while modifying data. There is no chance for the thread to clean up
after itself, unlock any held mutexes, etc. In short, use this
function only if absolutely necessary.

For this reason, it is much more common to write the target function for the thread to periodically check a flag which is modified by the main thread and gracefully exit if needed.
With standard python threads, I commonly use a simple threading.Lock which starts in a locked state, and is un-locked when the thread should exit. The thread periodically checks this lock by attempting to acquire it (without waiting), and if successful the thread performs cleanup and exits.
QThread seems to offer a somewhat pre-built solution for this in the form of the functions: QThread.requestInterruption, and QThread.isInterruptionRequested. I have never personally used this functionality, as I try to keep my thread functions as simple as possible, which to me means interacting with Qt as little as possible. Standard python threads are capable of emitting pre-defined signals, and reading class attributes (or other global/nonlocal state). This, to me, has always been plenty of inter-thread communication.
